# How to draw tangent line of an arbitrary point on a path in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote, metapost

Suppose I specify some node as occurring at some point on a path. Say for example the node `(P)` defined on the following path.

```
\path[draw] (0,9) to[out=-90,in=180] (9,0) node[pos=0.7,circle] (P) {};
```

I would now like to draw the tangent line at `(P)` to indicate the slope of the curve at that point.

Comment: Is it wise to use the standard definition of the derivative for you? I mean put another invisible node very close to it, say `pos=0.695`, and draw a line over them and extend the line.

Comment: No problem, that happens to me a lot. :)

Answer (score 75):

Here's an approach that uses the `decorations.markings` library to place support coordinates at a specified distance along a path, which can be used to set a local coordinate system at a later time to draw tangents or orthogonal lines.

You specify a tangent point by using `tangent=<pos>` in your first path. In a later path, you can then set `use tangent` to set a local coordinate system for that path: `(0,0)` is the tangent point itself, `(1,0)` is 1 unit along the tangent line, `(0,1)` is one unit along the orthogonal line.

You can specify `tangent=<pos>` multiple times in your original path. You can then specify which tangent point to use for a new path by calling `use tangent=<count>`, where the tangent points are numbered in the order they were specified in the original path.

Using these styles, the following code

```
\draw [
    tangent=0.4,
    tangent=0.56
] (0,0)
    to [out=20,in=120] (5,2)
    to [out=-60, in=110] (9,1);
\draw [blue, thick, use tangent] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [orange, thick, use tangent=2] (-2,0) -- (2,0) (0,0) -- (0,1);
```

would yield this

[image]

---

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    tangent/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,% switch on markings
            mark=
                at position #1
                with
                {
                    \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
                }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    use tangent/.style={
        shift=(tangent point-#1),
        x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
        y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
    },
    use tangent/.default=1
]
\draw [
    tangent=0.4,
    tangent=0.56
] (0,0)
    to [out=20,in=120] (5,2)
    to [out=-60, in=110] (9,1);
\draw [blue, thick, use tangent] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [orange, thick, use tangent=2] (-2,0) -- (2,0) (0,0) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sweet! I was doing this manually before.

Comment: The advantage of using the markings library (instead of just putting two points close to each other using `pos`) is that you actually have a tangential coordinate system at the time the marking is drawn, so it should be somewhat more accurate.

Comment: Indeed it is a more structured solution than the hack. But do you know by any chance how they(you?) implement the orientation of the coordinate system at the tangent point?

Comment: Good question, and it turns out that it's actually not a different approach from the one you mentioned. The `decorations.markings` library just uses a very short distance (1 sp, which is 1/65536 of a pt) for orienting the coordinate system.

Comment: How to use this with `\coordinate`?

Comment: Oh, I found out: `\coordinate [use tangent=2] (B) at (0,0.5)` does not seems to work, while `\path[use tangent=2, shape=coordinate] (0,0.5) coordinate (A)` seems to work. Not sure why...

Comment: @AkiRoss: `\coordinate [use tangent=2] (B) at (0,0.5);` works fine for me. Are you maybe using an older version of TikZ (the current one is 2.1)?

Comment: @Jake, I am using 2.1, too

Comment: Very nice. But the code can be realy simpler like this :
`\tikzset{draw at position/.style 2 args={decoration={markings, mark=at position #1 with {#2} }, postaction=decorate}}` and then you can use `[draw at position={.5}{\draw[blue] (-1,0)--(1,0);}]`

Comment: @Kpym: Sure, for some cases that might be all you need. However, for more complicated cases (like http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107912/2552) I much prefer the syntax that results from using my answer.

Comment: I came across one issue using this (very nice!) style: in pgfplots, it doesn't work combined with the `smooth` style. Explanation of the `dimension too large` error that occurs is in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170595/tikz-decorations-markings-cause-dimension-too-large; I simply removed the `smooth` style since I had enough data points anyway.

Comment: @GeertF You could simply do the plot twice, once with `smooth` and once with `tangent=...,samples=200,draw=none` to get the tangent. If you run the second plot from the x value at which you'd like to draw the tangent, you just put `tangent=0` and have the tangent right where you want to have it.

Answer (score 19):

For comparison, this is how one can draw a tangent in Metapost.

Metapost has a notion of *time* along a path. The first point on a path has `time=0,` the 2nd point has `time=1`, and so on. The operator `point .. of <path>` picks a point at a particular time along a path. The operator `direction ... of <path>` gives the direction of the curve at that time---which is precisely the tangent of the curve. These two operators can be combined to draw the tangent at any point on a curve.

[image]

The code below is in ConTeXt, but it will also work with standalone Metapost or LaTeX + emp or LaTeX + gmp.

```
\starttext

\startMPpage[offset=3mm]

  % Specify a path
  path p;
  p := (0,0) {dir 20} .. {dir -60} (5,2)  .. {dir 20} (9,1);
  p := p scaled 1cm;

  % Draw the path
  draw p withpen pencircle scaled 1bp withcolor red;

  % Specify a time along the path
  numeric ta; ta := 0.6;

  % Pick the point at that time
  pair a;     a := point ta of p;

  % Draw the point
  fill fullcircle scaled 3bp shifted a;

  % Draw a tangent at a particular point
  path tangent; tangent := (-2cm,0) -- (2cm,0);
  tangent := tangent rotated (angle direction ta of p) shifted a;

  draw tangent withcolor blue;


\stopMPpage


\stoptext
```

Comment: Maybe you should add a few words about the `whatever` operator? I am not a scientist, but metapost ability to deal with equations could be emphasized that way.

Comment: @sztruks: But this solution does not use the `whatever` operator.

Comment: Yes, I know, I was thinking about introducing a trick using it, but this is far beyond my skills.

Answer (score 17):

(For further readers). This is my try:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,7.5) .. controls (5,15.5) and (4,0.5) .. (12.5,7.5)
  node[sloped, inner xsep=20mm, inner ysep=0, fill, pos=0.5, red] (P) {};
\filldraw (P) circle(2pt); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

**Remark:** This trick does not works for predefined curves like `ellipse`, `circle`, ... because `pos` of `node` doesn't works properly as I know.

Comment: +1 That's really great, bravo!

Comment: @AndréC, Is it really deserve +100 (or any) award? This is just a simple answer.

Comment: The question of building tangents is a recurrent one. For example, the same question can be found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461573/138900 Your answer is remarkable because it is very simple and easy to understand. This is the most important criterion in an answer: simplicity and efficiency. Do a lot with little. You did what no one else before you thought of doing. Congratulations!

Comment: Would you have an idea on why this code: \draw [purple, xshift=4cm, yshift=4cm, very thick] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(0,0) (1.25,-0.10) (2.9, 3.45) (4.2,4.2)} node[sloped,inner xsep=1.5cm,inner ysep=1.5pt, fill,pos=2.12,red] (P) {}; produces a tangent that's horizontal (and centered at 0 instead of 2.12) despite that the curve doesn't have a horizontal tangent at that point?

Comment: @thermomagneticcondensedboson: First `pos` argument should be between 0 and 1. Secondly, I think `node` is not able to recognize a curve constructed by `coordinate` and points.

Comment: @AndréC Is there a way to draw the tangent before drawing the curve? I mean below the curve.

Comment: @berkus I don't understand your question, what do you mean by drawing a tangent under the curve?

Comment: @AndréC I mean is there a way to change the draw order. First the red tangent, then the black curve, so the red curve would not overwrite the black line.

Comment: @berkus I am not sure if this is possible with this solution, I have a doubt about it. It is possible with others. Ask a new question, greater TikZ specialists than me can look into this problem.

Comment: @berkus can't you just draw the curve in white, then the tangent in black, then the curve again ?

Answer (score 15):

Jake's solution is really nice. But if you want to draw a tangent in a plot, let's say,  over `x=1` you have to guess what position (`pos=?`) to use.
Here is a solution that use `/tikz/turn` key.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[domain=0:1] plot (\x,{sqrt(\x)}) {[turn] (-1,0) coordinate(t1) (2,0) coordinate(t2)};
  \draw[domain=1:3] plot (\x,{sqrt(\x)});
  \draw[red] (t1)--(t2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

This method has some issues :

- You can easily use it only with plots (because you have to stop drawing the curve at the given point).
- There is a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/342/) in `[turn]` when used with `plot` combined with some transform (rotate, shift, scale, ...).

So this is not really complete method, but I put it here for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

The following `tikz` code is a result of a double translation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{cff0000}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{c0000ff}{RGB}{0,0,255}


\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt,x=0.80pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[cm={{0.996,0.0,0.0,0.996,(0.0,0.0)}}]
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(57.1229,171.308)}}]
    \path[draw=cff0000,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.803pt] (0.0000,0.0000) .. controls (63.5042,-23.1136) and
      (123.7280,-141.1820) .. (166.7340,-66.6936) .. controls (192.1080,-22.7441)
      and (250.0570,-15.1248) .. (300.1210,-33.3468);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(57.1229,171.308)}}]
    \path[fill=black] (111.2830,-82.0534) .. controls (111.2830,-84.0025) and
      (109.7030,-85.5826) .. (107.7540,-85.5826) .. controls (105.8050,-85.5826) and
      (104.2250,-84.0025) .. (104.2250,-82.0534) .. controls (104.2250,-80.1043) and
      (105.8050,-78.5242) .. (107.7540,-78.5242) .. controls (109.7030,-78.5242) and
      (111.2830,-80.1043) .. (111.2830,-82.0534) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(57.1229,171.308)}}]
    \path[draw=c0000ff,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (50.9475,-47.1101) -- (164.5610,-116.9970);
  \end{scope}
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It was obtained by means of `svg2tikz` from the `t.svg` file,
which was built by `asy -f svg t.asy` command. The source text is
a direct line-by-line translation from the `MetaPost` version 
(`MP` code is commented with `//`), 
basically a minor syntactic differences, `t.asy`:

```
    size(300);
//
//  % Specify a path
//  path p;
    path p;
//  p := (0,0) {dir 20} .. {dir -60} (5,2)  .. {dir 20} (9,1);
    p  = (0,0) {dir( 20)} .. {dir( -60)} (5,2)  .. {dir( 20)} (9,1);
//  p := p scaled 1cm;
    p  = scale(1cm)*p;
//  % Draw the path
//  draw p withpen pencircle scaled 1bp withcolor red;
    draw(p, red+1bp);

//  % Specify a time along the path
//  numeric ta; ta := 0.6;
    real ta=0.6;
//  % Pick the point at that time
//  pair a;     a := point ta of p;
    pair a = point(p, ta);

//  % Draw the point
//  fill fullcircle scaled 3bp shifted a;
    fill(shift(a)*scale(3bp)*unitcircle);
//
//  % Draw a tangent at a particular point
//  path tangent; tangent := (-2cm,0) -- (2cm,0);
    path tangent=(-2cm,0) -- (2cm,0);
//  tangent := tangent rotated (angle direction ta of p) shifted a;
    tangent = shift(a)*rotate(degrees(dir(p,ta)))*tangent;
//
//  draw tangent withcolor blue;
    draw(tangent,blue);
```

Comment: Nice. Such a translation is a really nice way to learn asymptote.

Answer (score 10):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\edef\N{10}
\edef\X(#1){#1/\N*cos(#1)}
\edef\Y(#1){#1/\N*sin(#1)}

\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=100,arrows=->}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psparametricplot{0}{5 Pi mul}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
    \curvepnode{13 Pi mul 3 div}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}{P}
    \normalvec(Ptang){Pnorm}
    \psxline[linecolor=red](P){-(Ptang)}{Ptang} 
    \psxline[linecolor=green](P){}{-(Pnorm)}
    \psxline[linecolor=blue](P){}{(Pnorm)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Tutorial

1. `\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}` is used to get a tight PDF output with an additional border of `3pt` (by default `border=0.50001bp`).
2. `\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}` is to load `pst-node` (containing macros pertaining to node operations) and `pst-plot` (containing macros for ploting).
3. Parametric representation of a spiral. Using parametric representation is a good practice as it can handle almost everything.

   ```
   \edef\N{10}
   \edef\X(#1){#1/\N*cos(#1)}
   \edef\Y(#1){#1/\N*sin(#1)}
   ```
4. `\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=100,arrows=->}` to switch to algebraic parser (as opposed to default one in RPN), change the default `plotpoints` from 50 to 100 (making the plot smoother), and change the default `arrows` from `-` (none) to `->` (arrow head at the final end), respectively.
5. `\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)...\end{pspicture}` is the canvas specification. It should be intuitive if you have learnt Cartesian coordinate system in the playgroup.
6. `\psparametricplot{0}{5 Pi mul}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}`  to plot the given spiral from `0` to `5 Pi mul` (5π). Irrelevant information: *If you want to know how I show the π, use `ALT+227` in Windows*.
7. `\curvepnode{13 Pi mul 3 div}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}{P}` to specify a single point `P` on the spiral. It is accidentally chosen at `t=13/3 π`. One important thing to know is `\curvepnode` gives us an **UNIT TANGENT VECTOR** called `Ptang` (derived from `<your point name>tang`) free of charge. No unit normal vector is given. Is it strange? Please ask the PSTricks maintainers for the reason!
8. `\normalvec(Ptang){Pnorm}` is used to rotate the `Ptang` about the origin 90 degrees counter clockwise. The vector length is kept the same -- in this case the length is 1 unit. But you can use `\normalvect` for any vector whether it is unit vector or not.
9. `\psxline[linecolor=red](A){<vector expression>}{<another vector expression>}` is used to draw a point from `A + <vector expression>`   to `A + <another vector expression>`. Is it confusing? Let's take one example:

   ```
   \psxline[linecolor=red](P){-(Ptang)}{Ptang}
   ```

   that represents a line drawn from `P+(-Ptang)` to `P+Ptang`. still get confused? Let's consider the next one:

   ```
   \psxline[linecolor=green](P){}{-(Pnorm)}
   ```

   that represents a line drawn from `P+(0,0)` to `P+(-Ptang)`.
10. Compile the code with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` (much faster) or `xelatex` (much slower).

### For a curve consisting of a list of arbitrary points

The following is the solution for a curve consisting of a list of arbitrary points. Unfortunately, the point through which the tangent and normal lines pass is not on the curve. This problem has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108089/19356) so you can find there whether or not it has be fixed.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,3)
    \pscurve[curvature=1 1 1](0,0)(1,2)(2,1)(4,2)(6,1)
    \psTangentLine[Tnormal,linecolor=blue](2,1)(4,2)(6,1){3}{0.25}
    \psTangentLine[linecolor=red](2,1)(4,2)(6,1){3}{1}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=green](OCurve){3pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good one. my upvotes are empty i will once recharged.

Answer (score 10):

**Update an Asymptote answer (19 March 2022)** simple and direct way, both 2D and 3D curves. TikZ considers tangents/normals as decorations; meanwhile Asymptote treat them as true paths.

*For 2D curve:*

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
path mypath=(0,0) ..controls (0,0)+5dir(70) and (8,3)+5dir(-120) .. (8,3);
draw(mypath);
real t=.2;
pair P=point(mypath,t);
pair Pt=dir(mypath,t);        // tangent vector at P
pair Pn=rotate(90)*Pt;        // normal vector at P
draw(mypath);
draw(P-2Pt--P+4Pt,red);
draw(P-2Pn--P+2Pn,blue);

dot(P);
shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

*For 3D curve:* Note that `triple perp(triple v)` return a unit vector perpendicular to a given unit vector `v`.

In the following figure, the tangent line is in red, the normal plane is in green.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
import three;
unitsize(2cm);
path3 g=(1,0,0)..(0,1,1)..(-1,0,0)..(0,-1,1)..cycle;

real t=.3;
triple P=point(g,t);
triple Pt=dir(g,t);       // the tangent vector at P

triple Pn1=perp(Pt);     
triple Pn2=cross(Pt,Pn1);
//dot(P+Pn1^^P+Pn2,red);    // 2 points on the normal plane at P
path3 Pnormal=plane(1.5Pn1,1.7Pn2,P-.8Pn1-.7Pn2); // the normal plane at P

draw(g);
draw(P-2Pt--P+3Pt,red);  
draw(Pnormal,blue);
draw(surface(Pnormal),lightgreen+opacity(.5));
```

**Old answer**
C.F.G.'s trick is nice! First I modify a bit his trick: `[inner ysep=.5pt]` to control thickness of tangent, and adding `[rotate=90]` to get normal segment. Not that with this trick, there is a restriction: both tangent and normal segments must have the same midpoint at underlying point on the curve.

Then I remove this restriction using `pic`, also with handy option `[sloped]`. Now drawing tangents and normals seem to be done, except predefined curves like `ellipse`, `circle`, .... However, we can use their parameterization expressions, and plot directly ^^

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
% 1st way with node (based on C.F.G's trick)  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ..controls +(70:5) and +(-120:5) .. (8,3)
% for tangent
node[sloped,inner xsep=1.5cm,inner ysep=.5pt, fill,pos=.12,red] (P) {}
% for normal (just add [rotate=90])
node[rotate=90,sloped,inner xsep=1.5cm,inner ysep=.5pt,fill,pos=.12,blue] {}
;
\fill (P) circle(2pt) node[above]{P}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

% 2nd way with pic (more handy) 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tangent/.pic={
\draw (-1.5,0)--(2.5,0);
}]
\draw (0,0) ..controls +(70:5) and +(-120:5) .. (8,3)
coordinate[pos=.87] (Q)
% for tangent
pic[pos=.87,sloped,cyan,thick]{tangent}
% for normal (just add [rotate=90])
pic[pos=.87,sloped,rotate=90,brown,thick]{tangent}
;
\fill (Q) circle(2pt) node[above]{Q}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Update** As AndreC suggested, I make `pic` named `segment` with 3 parameters: angle #1 left #2 right #3, where `angle 0` is for tangent, `angle 90` is for normal, #2 and #3 are for length of segment to 2 endpoints of segment from underlying point on the curve. Option on thickness can be put later when using `pic` with `line width` option.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/segment/.style args=
{angle #1 left #2 right #3}{
code={\draw[rotate=#1] (180:#2)--(0:#3);}}} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mecurve{(0,0) ..controls +(60:6) and +(-120:6) .. (8,2)}
\draw \mecurve;
\foreach \t in {.1,.5,...,1}
\path \mecurve 
% for tangent {angle 0}
pic[pos=\t,sloped,cyan,thick]
{segment=angle 0 left 2 right 1.5}
% for normal {angle 90}
pic[pos=\t,sloped,orange,thick]
{segment=angle 90 left 1 right 2}
node[pos=\t]{$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As an applicaton, we can mark along curve (may use when the curve has quite small slope).

```
\foreach \t in {0,.025,...,1}
\path \mecurve 
pic[pos=\t,sloped,orange,line width=1pt]
{segment=angle 90 left 2mm right 2mm};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 In this case, why not make the thickness and length of the tangent/normal two optional parameters?

Comment: @AndreC: Sure, we can do that!

Comment: With rotation as the third optional parameter, it will be complete:-)

Comment: Nice, but instead of naming the parameters by left and right, I suggest `length` and `thickness` (or even `width`).

Comment: `thickness` is not necessary parameterized, can be put when using `pic`. Moreover, in `segment`, then length of segment is `#2 + #3` which is easier to control

Comment: The terms left and right are relative to the page as are the above and below options of TikZ. In the case of a tangent, there is no left and right, since it is relative to the curve itself and not to the page. A tangent, on the other hand, has a length and a thickness.

Comment: I know `left` and `right` is relative, but it is convention in several places in pgfmanual (see page 637 on library `decoration.making` for example. Note that `marking` is a kind of `pic`). If we use length, then there is 2 lengths: one to the left and one to the right. Anyway, if you give full code for `segment`, I will check and choose the better.

Comment: In the manual, left and right are always relative to the page as well as above (or up) and below (or down).  And this even in decorations-marking. Giving a meaningful vocabulary makes it easier to use an order. But, it's up to you, since you're the one who does it. Everyone can rename these parameters at will.

Comment: Would you have an idea on why this code:  \draw [purple, xshift=4cm, yshift=4cm, very thick] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(0,0) (1.25,-0.10) (2.9, 3.45) (4.2,4.2)}
node[sloped,inner xsep=1.5cm,inner ysep=1.5pt, fill,pos=2.12,red] (P) {};     produces a tangent that's horizontal (and centered at 0 instead of 2.12) despite that the curve doesn't have a horizontal tangent at that point?

Comment: I have just added a crucial update: General solution for tangents and normals of general (2D and 3D) curves with Asymptote.

Answer (score 5):

My try of using the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tzhelplines*(10,4)
\tztos"curve"(0,0)[out=20,in=120](5,2)[out=-60,in=110](9,1);
\tztangentat[blue,thick]{curve}{3.6}[2:6]
\tztangentat[orange,thick]{curve}{5}[4:6]
\tzslopeat[orange,thick,tzextend={0}{1cm}]{curve}{5}{.1pt}[90]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `spath3` TikZ library ([ctan](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) or [github](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3)) introduced a `transform to` coordinate system which sets the coordinates so that the origin is at a specified point on a curve and the `x`-axis points along the tangent at that point.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25928/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw,spath/save=curve] (0,9) to[out=-90,in=180] node[pos=0.7,circle,draw] (P) {}  (9,0);
\draw[spath/transform to={curve}{0.7}] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Curve with tangent line at arbitrary point]

Comment: My curiosity: There is not the keyword "tangent" in your code???

Comment: @BlackMild I have code that calculates tangents to curves but it's not exposed at a user level (yet), rather it's used in things like this.  I guess my thinking was that it's not much use simply calculating a tangent - pretty much everything one wants to do with that calculation starts with a transformation.  If you think it would be useful to make the tangent calculation available at the user level then that would be easy enough to do - open an issue on github for it.

Comment: Very nice! I believe you can remove the `(P)`. :-)

Comment: @frougon Yes, though I was trying to keep the code as similar to that in the question as I could (though I had to adjust the order of the node and the final coordinate to get the node in the right place).