# PGFkeys problem. Meta arrow tips with parameters works only when I use different line width. Why?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

The solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28920/arrow-scaling-problem-how-can-i-zoom-properly-a-very-tiny-part-of-a-drawing) has a problem. Let re-write a minimum example

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{arrow length/.initial = 6pt,
         arrow angle/.initial  = 45}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{adj}{adj}{
\pgfarrowsleftextend{0pt}
\pgfarrowsrightextend{.5\pgflinewidth}
}
{
\pgfkeys{/tikz/arrow length/.get=\arrow@length}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/arrow angle/.get=\arrow@angle}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\arrow@angle}{\arrow@length*tan(\arrow@angle)}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt} % do not dash
\pgfsetroundcap % fix cap
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%{\pgfpoint{-4\arrowsize}{4\arrowsize}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\arrow@length}{\arrow@angle}}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%{\pgfpoint{-4\arrowsize}{4\arrowsize}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\arrow@length}{-\arrow@angle}}
\pgfusepathqstroke
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[help lines] (-3,0)grid(3,4);

% Arrow 1
\draw[arrow length = 24pt,
      arrow angle  = 15,
      adj-adj,line width=1.5pt](-2.5,1)--(2.5,1)node[right]{1}
                                                node[above,midway]{First arrow};

% Arrow 2 - Doesn't change anything (same line width then before)
\draw[arrow length = 400cm, %<- Big value to show you it doesn't work
      arrow angle  = 720,   %<- Big value to show you it doesn't work
      adj-adj,line width=1.5pt](-2.5,2)--(2.5,2)node[right]{2}
                                                node[above,midway]{Arrows not changed};

% Arrow 3 - Change arrow because the line width is changed
\draw[adj-adj,line width=1.501pt](-2.5,3)--(2.5,3)node[right]{3}%<- Line width little changed
                                                  node[above,midway]{Arrows changed};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following result
[image]

The problem is that the arrow length and arrow angle style effect the arrow on line of different line width. In the Arrow 2(see the above listing) I apply very big values of them but there is no effects because the line width is the same of the previous line. The following one, instead, I apply a line width of 0.001pt more than before and the options changes the arrow tips.

Did I use wrong the pgfkeys? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but this listing respond well to my needs

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{arrow angle/.code     = \def\arrow@angle{#1},
         arrow angle/.default  = 45,
         arrow length/.code    = \pgfsetarrowoptions{adj}{#1},
         arrow length/.default = 4pt
         }

\pgfarrowsdeclare{adj}{adj}{
\pgfarrowsrightextend{.5\pgflinewidth}
}
{
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\arrow@angle}{\pgfgetarrowoptions{adj}*tan(\arrow@angle)}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt} % do not dash
\pgfsetroundcap % fix cap
%\pgfsetstrokecolor{red}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgfgetarrowoptions{adj}}{\arrow@angle}}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgfgetarrowoptions{adj}}{-\arrow@angle}}
\pgfusepathqstroke
}
\makeatother




\draw[help lines] (-3,0)grid(3,4);

% Arrow 1 - Default value
\draw[line width   = 1.5pt, %<---- HERE I SET 1.5pt
      arrow length, % 4pt
      arrow angle,  % 45
      adj-adj](-2.5,1)--(2.5,1)node[right]{1}
                               node[above,midway]{1.5pt};

% Arrow 2 
\draw[line width   = 2pt,
      arrow length = 10pt, 
      arrow angle  = 15,
      adj-adj](-2.5,2)--(2.5,2)node[right]{2}
                               node[above,midway]{2pt};

% Arrow 3 
\draw[line width   = 1.5pt, %<---- HERE I SET 1.5pt AGAIN
      arrow length=1cm, 
      arrow angle=15,
      adj-adj](-2.5,3)--(2.5,3)node[right]{3}%<- Line width little changed
                               node[above,midway]{1.5pt again but different parameters};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is the following:
[image]

It seems to work.

I want a meta arrow tip because when you draw a very tiny part and you want to zoom it with  tikz library spy, the result is not good. To understand what I mean, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28920/arrow-scaling-problem-how-can-i-zoom-properly-a-very-tiny-part-of-a-drawing) the picture I posted. With this solution I have the total control on the very small drawing and it is good. The result, applied to my drawing, is the following

[image]

I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 2):

According to p.611 of the PGF manual:

> - The code will be executed only once, namely the first time the arrow
>   tip needs to be drawn. The resulting low-level driver commands are
>   protocolled and stored away. In all subsequent uses of the arrow tip,
>   the protocolled code is directly inserted.
> - However, the code will be
>   executed anew for each line width. Thus, an arrow of line width 2pt
>   may result in a different protocol than the same arrow for a line
>   width of 0.4pt.

...in other words, it looks like this is an intentional feature. I'm not sure why you need multiple different arrow sizes for a single line width to solve your original problem, but if you do, it might be better to define these as different arrow types.

Answer (score 2):

Ant is right, normally arrow tips are figured out once for each line width and then saved.  This speeds up the rendering considerably.  (PGF calls this *prototyping*.)  But it is possible to specify other options which should also trigger a recomputation.  This is done using the commands `\pgfsetarrowoptions` and `\pgfgetarrowoptions`.  The manual explains this on p613 (version 2.10) and gives an example in the following text.

I used this in an answer at [TikZ: changing colour of a path half way along](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/tikz-changing-colour-of-a-path-half-way-along/19910#19910) to specify the angle at which the two lines meet (something that has to be specified on a per-use basis).  The link there is to the actual answer where this is used (given that I gave several answers to that question!).  I think it's close enough to your case that it should be possible to adapt, but if not just ask!