# How to draw tangent vectors and component vectors on a curve  

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks

I am searching for a way to have a figure drawn using LaTeX. I am aware of some packages TikZ and PSTricks that could accomplish this, and have been tinkering around with them recently but do not have enough skill set at the moment to accomplish this drawing. Is there a way someone can accomplish the drawing, preferably with TikZ but could be any package your most comfortable with in a reduced amount of coding (non-advanced) to where I could understand what is happening from the code to the picture. If this is not possible, then I will have to study the package more and work with it until I understand the method (code) to create the graphic. The drawing is below.

**Note:** This is a rough sketch. The optimal output would have smooth quadratic curves and all quantities are vectors.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To give you a correctly answer, I need to add a code to put together all the next parts .
The trick here: we place a node on the path with option `sloped` so we a get a tangent. To show this tangent line, we place the node with `anchor=south west`. The corner of the bow is now correctly placed,and finally we give correct size to the node.

All the parts together:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}       
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[allow upside down]
\draw[red,line width=1pt] (0,0) .. controls ++(1,6) and ++(-1,2) .. (10,4)
      node[sloped,inner sep=0cm,above,pos=.5,
      anchor=south west,
      minimum height=(10.5)*0.3cm,minimum width=(10.5)*.3cm](N){};

\path (N.south west)%
           edge[-stealth',blue] node[left] {$\vec{ n}$} (N.north west)
           edge[-stealth',blue] node[above] {$\vec{ t}$} (N.south east);
\draw[-stealth',gray]  (N.south west)  --%
      node[below] {$\vec{t_a}$} (N.south west -| N.south east); 
\draw[-stealth',gray]  (N.south west)  --%
      node[right] {$\vec{t_o}$} (N.south west |- N.south east);

  \end{tikzpicture}    
 \end{document}
```

Complement about tangents and normals

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}   
\usepackage{tikz}       
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows}      
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[allow upside down]
    \draw[red,line width=1pt] (0,0)
    .. controls +(right:6cm) and +(left:4cm) .. (2,6)
    \foreach \p in {0,5,...,100} {
      node[sloped,inner sep=0cm,above,pos=\p*0.01,
      anchor=south west,
      minimum height=(10+\p)*0.03cm,minimum width=(10+\p)*0.03cm]
      (N \p){}
    }
    .. controls +(right:2cm) and +(right:3cm) .. (6,2)
    \foreach \p in {5,10,...,100} {
      node[sloped,inner sep=0cm,above,pos=\p*0.01,
      anchor=south west,
      minimum height=(110-\p)*0.03cm,minimum width=(110-\p)*0.03cm]
      (N2 \p){}
    }
    ;
    \foreach \p in {0,5,...,100} {
      \draw[-latex,blue] (N \p.south west) -- (N \p.north west);
      \draw[-latex,color=green!50!black] (N \p.south west) -- (N \p.south east);
    }
    \foreach \p in {5,10,...,100} {
      \draw[-latex,blue] (N2 \p.south west) -- (N2 \p.north west);
      \draw[-latex,color=green!50!black] (N2 \p.south west) -- (N2 \p.south east);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\coordinate  (B) at (3,4);
\draw
    [->]
    (A) --  node [above] {\(\vec v\)}(B)  
    ; 
    \draw[red,->] (A)-- node [above] {\(\vec a\)}(A|-B) ; 
    \draw[red,->] (A|-B)--node [left] {\(\vec b\)}(B) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Next a code to show how to draw component vector (it's possible to create a macro to do this.
Instead of `\draw [->](A) -- (B)  node [above,midway] {\(\vec v\)};`you can write `\draw [->](A) --  node [above] {\(\vec v\)}(B);`.

With pgf 2.1 CVS now it's possible to use a new option `edge label` or `edge node` to place 
directly the label (see the last picture)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}   
\usepackage{tikz}       
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows}      
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
  \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\coordinate  (B) at (3,4);     
    \draw [->](A) --  node [above] {\(\vec v\)}(B);
    \path (A)--(A|-B) coordinate (C) ;
    \draw[red,->] (A) -- node[left] {\(\vec a\)} (C) ; 
    \draw[red,->] (C)-- node[above] {\(\vec b\)}(B) ;  
\end{tikzpicture} 

 \end{document}
```

[image]

**Only with PGF 2.10 CVS**

[image]
[image]

Comment: I recommend this solution too: 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz

Comment: @Azoun thanks for the link. I did not know the method of Jake. Very interesting !

Comment: @Altermundus: Thanks. Very interesting method of approach using the `foreach` method. +1

Answer (score 19):

change the function to whatever you need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(9,6)
\psaxes[ticksize=0 5pt]{->}(9,6)
\psset{algebraic,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowscale=2} \def\function{-x*(x-8)/3}
\psplot[linewidth=1.5pt,algebraic]{0}{8}{\function}
\psplotTangent*[linecolor=red,arrows=->]{6}{-2.5}{\function}
\uput{10pt}[45](*5 {\function}){$\vec{v}$}
\pcline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue]{->}(*6 {\function})(*6 {\function-1})
\naput[npos=0.95]{$\vec{a_y}$}
\pcline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue]{->}(*6 {\function-1})(4.5,0|*6 {\function-1})
\naput{$\vec{a_x}$}
\pcline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue]{->}(*6 {\function})(4.5,0|*6 {\function-1})
\nbput{$\vec{a}$}
\pcline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=green]{->}(4.5,0|*6 {\function-1})(4.5,0|*5 {\function+0.5})
\naput{$\vec{\omega}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and with the latest pstricks-add.tex from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pstricks-add/:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=4}
\begin{pspicture}(1,-1)(4,1)
\pscurve[showpoints=true](2.1,-0.2)(2.5,0.2)(3.2,0.4)(3.8,-0.2)
\psTangentLine[Tnormal,arrows=->,linecolor=red](2.5,0.2)(3.2,0.4)(3.8,-0.2){3.5}{0.5}
\psTangentLine[arrows=->,linecolor=blue](2.5,0.2)(3.2,0.4)(3.8,-0.2){3.5}{0.5}
\pcline[linestyle=dashed]{->}(OCurve)(ETangent|OCurve)\naput{$v_x$}
\pcline[linestyle=dashed]{->}(ETangent|OCurve)(ETangent)\naput{$v_y$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Herb! Is there a way to not break through the function with the component a_y, i.e., position it a little tighter inside.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I can't get it to work for tangent points other than the one you showed (for example, `\psTangentLine...{3.0}{0.5}` doesn't give a line that's tangential to the path). Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9):

The [TikZ manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) provides some excellent tutorials. The first two or three of them can be done in a matter of hours and will teach you enough of the basics so that you should be able to solve your problem.

To give some examples about the "trickier" parts of your drawing: You can create an arrow with a label like this:

```
\draw
    [->] % Add arrow tip at the end
    (0,0) -- (3,1) % Start/end coordinate
    node [above, midway] {\(\vec a\)} % Add a label centered on the arrow just drawn
    ;
```

[image]

To find out how to draw dashed lines, search the manual for "dashed". The manual is excellent, and simply searching it will answer many questions you come up with.
Drawing the curve is possible with Bezier curves, they are briefly explained in the first tutorial.

That should be all you need. (And using TikZ gets better, only the first few pictures feel like swimming through honey. And then it becomes quite a lot of fun sometimes.)

Comment: @nightowl For that matter, the easiest way to find the manual of an installed package is to write `texdoc <nameofpackage>` in a terminal, so `texdoc tikz` will give you pgfmanual.pdf. (This also works in the start menu of Windows 7 (perhaps Vista as well), so you can just hit the Windows key, type `texdoc tikz` and hit enter.)

Comment: Thanks. But does not seem to work on windows 7.

Comment: @nightowl Forgot to say that I have TeXlive, perhaps it doesn't work with MikTeX. You could try `mthelp` instead of `texdoc`, as [that is MikTeX's version](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/mthelp.html).

Comment: @CounterTerrorist and TorbjornT: It works the way Torborn said, it just was the wrong file name, should been as Counter said, `pgfmanual`. Thanks