# Line tangent to a a curve (using plot or controls), starting at a point

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw lines that are parallel to a curve starting at a point.

The curve could be a curve drawn using 3 point as my example below did, but alternatively could be a curve drawn using the `\draw () .. controls () and () .. ()` command. Preferably it would work either way.

This is the picture of what I am after:

[image]

**Explanation**

I have to curves, u_0 and u_1, and a point I_0. I want to find the line that goes from this point (I_0) and is tangent to the first curve (u_0), and the line that goes from (I_0) and is tangent to the second curve (u_1).

Then, I want to find a line that is parallel to the line tangent to (u_1), and this line needs to be tangent to (u_0). *If the line can start and stop at the axis without using the shorten commands even better*.

For now, I found the tangents and the start and finish points of the parallel line with trial and error, but I have dozens of such pictures to drawn and I need a better way of doing this.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % axes
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
    \draw (origin) -- (0,6.5) node[left]{$x_{2}$};
    \draw (origin) -- (9.5,0) node[below]{$x_{1}$};
    % u_0
    \node (e) at (2.2,4.9) {};
    \node (f) at (3,3) {};
    \node (g) at (5,2.3) {};
    \draw[thick] plot[smooth,tension=0.9] coordinates {(e) (f) (g)} node[right]{$u_{0}$};
    % u_1
    \node (h) at (1.5,4.2) {};
    \node (b) at (2.4,2.3) {};
    \node (j) at (4.4,1.6) {};
    \draw[thick] plot[smooth,tension=0.9] coordinates {(h) (b) (j)} node[right]{$u_{1}$};
    % first budget line (I_0 to p_0)
    \coordinate[label=left:{\scriptsize$I_{0}$}] (i0) at (0,4.65);
    \draw (i0) -- (8.1,0); 
    % second budget line (I_0 to p_1)
    \coordinate (d) at (4.67,0) {};
    \draw (i0) -- (d);
    % dashed line
    \draw[densely dashed,style={shorten >=2.8cm,shorten <=-4.64cm}] (2.68,3.3)   -- +($(i0)-(d)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this help: [How to draw tangent line of an arbitrary point on a path in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz)?

Comment: @PeterGrill but wouldn't I have to specify the point in the curve the tangent line has to go through? (let me know if I misunderstood it). I tried that, but it is not really what I want. I want to specify a point outside of the curve (I_0), and I want a line tangent to the curve, and I don't care where in the curve the tangent point is (what I care about is the point outside of the curve, I_0)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I guess it comes down to figuring out the math to compute the tangent...

Comment: You can try using the tkz-fct package. It can compute the tangent of a curve. It uses Gnuplot.

Comment: One way of doing this (but extremely inefficient) would be to take samples points on the curve, and iterate over [the tangents to the curve at that point](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37866/how-to-draw-tangent-vectors-and-component-vectors-on-a-curve), and find all the points on the curve with the minimum (within some threshold) distance from the tangent line to the given point (there may be more than one), and then draw those lines. But, there must be an easier way.

Comment: tkz-fct  can not do anything in this situation. It needs an explicit formula. Certain conditions are required for the existence of tangents. I think it's difficult to avoid trial and error.

Comment: @PeterGrill yes, I think I really should try and use math, starting with the drawing of the curves. The theory I am trying to show in the pictures is all backed up by math. If I took the time to find the equation for the utility curves (the u_0 and u_1 curves) everything else would follow pretty easily. The problem for me was getting the equation of the curve that looked right and fitted in the axes the way I wanted. It seems like I should just do that...

Comment: @Altermundus Perhaps I could avoid trial and error if I draw the u curves using an equation rather than plot or controls?

Comment: @Vivi yes it's better using equations. Perhaps I can find a solution with `fp`. Logically the equations are function polynomial of degree 2 or 3 and in this case it's relatively easy with a paper and a pencil, with TeX, it's more difficult :) First you need to find a tangent at a curve from an extern point to get a slope; then you need to find the point of another curve where a tangent has the last slope.

Comment: @Altermundus The u functions would be something like u = ln(x1) + ln(x2) (they need to have the first derivatives positive and second derivatives negative -> more of one good gives you more utility, but the more of one good you have, the less extra utility you get for more of that good). Then the curves are drawn for a given utility, that is for u = k with k a constant. It is not too difficult, I just couldn't get a curve that would fit in the axes. But from what I can see, even though there is a big fixed cost to getting the right function, in the long run I will save time if I just do it...

Comment: Once I get this function it will be piece of cake getting the tangents... Maybe it is a good excuse to finally learn microeconomics (I was never good at it...)

Comment: piece of cake ? If you like cakes with a lot of cream and chocolate ! seriously, it depends of the functions

Comment: @Altermundus uh-oh... OK, maybe I shouldn't get too excited. I will work on this in the next few days, and make sure I let you know if I am successful (I will probably post one or two more questions on that anyway). Thanks heaps for the help :)

Comment: Ok I have time to clean my answer !

Comment: I think an automated approach as I suggested above would work, but might take some time to run.  Before I attempt that, for your case is there always **only one** line tangent to the curve and through the point?

Comment: Ok, after some more thought I think it is possible to automate this without requiring a equation for the curve. But, before I attempt to write this code have two questions: **1.** Will there ever be the case where there are two tangents of the curve that go thru the point? **2.** Would you be ok if it required you to provide some guess as to the range where the tangent would be? You could of course just give the domain as the guess of the range but that might take longer -- so this may not be an issue, but thought I would ask first.

Comment: 1. two distinct tangents that go through the same point in a curve? No. This is what I am trying to avoid: I want to show very clearly that the tangents points change when the budget constraint changes.  2. You mean the range in a general way, for example, the numbers between 0 and 6, or do you want the exact y coordinate? If the former, no problem; if the latter, it wouldn't help, I think (since if I knew the y number, I could easily figure out the x number).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think a decoration idea can be utilized here. As can be seen in the manual, the decoration declaration has a particular useful register that keeps the decoration angle defined as the tangent at the particular decoration segment. So I played around with that idea and here is the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\newcounter{loopcoun}
\setcounter{loopcoun}{0}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclaredecoration{findtan}{initial}{
\state{initial}[width=1mm,next state=findit]{
}
\state{findit}[width=1mm]{
\ifnum\value{loopcoun}<1
        \pgfpointanchor{i0}{center}
        \pgf@xa = \pgf@x
        \pgf@ya = \pgf@y
        \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(atan2(\pgf@xa,\pgf@ya)<\pgfdecoratedangle,1,}
        \ifx\pgfmathresult\@empty\relax
        \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
        \pgflineto{\pgfpointanchor{i0}{center}}
        \setcounter{loopcoun}{1}
        \else
        \fi
\else\fi
\pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
\state{final}[1mm]{
\setcounter{loopcoun}{0}
}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (8cm,5cm);
\node[fill,inner sep=1pt,circle] (i0) at (0,3) {};

\path[draw,decoration=findtan,postaction={decorate}] (2,3) .. controls (0,1) and (4,0) .. (5,1);
\path[red,draw,decoration=findtan,postaction={decorate}] (3,4) .. controls (2,1) and (5,2) .. (6,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The basic idea is that TikZ starts travelling on the curve little by little (given by the `width` option of the `\state` declaration) and do some stuff defined by the commands of that particular state. Basically, that defines the approximation resolution (reduce if necessary!).  Here I am calculating the angle of the tangent line and comparing it with the given `(i0)` point. If it satisfies the constraint I am drawing a line to the point and incrementing the counter such that the code gets executed only once. So this is a proof of the concept. If you don't increment the counter it would give all the points satisfying the condition. Note that we are really exploiting something that is not meant to behave like this at all so expect all kinds of strange results. At least it doesn't draw anything if there is no such point, please play around with the location of `(i0)` to see if there is any bugs.

I wrote up a slightly messy code that seemingly does what you wanted. The idea is that you supply some initial points and then draw the curves indicating the particular tangent point. Then if any, they will be collected as nodes under the generic name `(c-#)`. With this I did some tedious calculations using some geometry and draw the lines. There is much to improve obviously and hope it helps.

*edit*: the curves should start from top left to bottom right since the code marks the first eligible point. first of possibly many shortcomings...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,calc}
\newcounter{loopcoun}
\newcounter{cocounter}
\setcounter{cocounter}{0}
\setcounter{loopcoun}{0}
\makeatletter

\pgfkeys{/tikz/find tangent/.style={decoration=findtan,depoint=#1,postaction=decorate}}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/depoint/.code= \edef\pgf@pointname{#1}}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{findtan}{initial}{
\state{initial}[width=1mm,next state=findit]{
}
\state{findit}[width=1mm]{
\ifnum\value{loopcoun}<1
        \pgfpointanchor{\pgf@pointname}{center}
        \pgf@xa = \pgf@x
        \pgf@ya = \pgf@y
        \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(atan2(\pgf@xa,\pgf@ya)>\pgfdecoratedangle,1,0)}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0
        \stepcounter{cocounter}{1}
        \pgfcoordinate{c-\the\value{cocounter}}{\pgfpointorigin}
        \setcounter{loopcoun}{1}
        \else
        \fi
\else\fi
\pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
\state{final}[1mm]{
\setcounter{loopcoun}{0}
}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] (9cm,5cm);
\node[fill,inner sep=1pt,circle] (p0) at (0,3) {};
\node[fill,inner sep=1pt,circle] (p1) at (0,4) {};

\draw[find tangent=p0] (2,3) .. controls (0,1) and (4,0) .. (5,1);
\path[find tangent=p0] (3,4) .. controls (2,1) and (5,2) .. (6,1);
\draw[red,find tangent=p1] (3,4) .. controls (2,1) and (5,2) .. (6,1);

\draw let \p1 = (p0), \p2 = (c-1),\n2 = {atan2(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)},\n3 = {-\y1/sin(\n2)} in (p0) -- ++(\n2:\n3); 
\draw let \p1 = (p0), \p2 = (c-2),\n2 = {atan2(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)},\n3 = {-\y1/sin(\n2)} in (p0) -- ++(\n2:\n3); 
\draw[dashed] let \p1 = (p1), \p2 = (c-3),\n2 = {atan2(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)},\n3 = {-\y1/sin(\n2)} in (p1) -- ++(\n2:\n3); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! That was super-clever! I will need to adjust this to have the line continue on after the tangent, and also to be able to define the starting point (the i0) in the \draw command, since I might have more than one initial point in a figure, but it seems like this will work! (I am also quite busy now, so I can't play with the answer at the moment and won't accept it as correct until I have the chance to look at this more closely)

Comment: Interesting approach. I was afraid by time and precision but perhaps I was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for `pgfdecoratedangle`. I discover this useful macro. In a first time, I did not like the decoration library, but now with your code I think it's time to study this part of TikZ !

Comment: great, that's a good idea

Comment: @Vivi Thanks, hope it helps. I think it's better than nothing however it is pretty fragile. So handle with care :)

Comment: Getting PGF package errors for the second piece of code. Any particular care needed to compile it? Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickT Must be the TikZ version change. `atan2` function now works with `(y,x)` instead of the `(x,y)` in the old version.

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

It's perhaps possible with Asymptote but not with TikZ. You need to resolve an equation to get the first tangent from `I_0` to `u_1` , because you don't know where is the point of intersection with the curve.

I think a fine method without (and perhaps with) equations of the curves is to use a visual way:

**Step 1** We try to get an approximate value for the slope of the tangente from `I_0` to `u_1`. This tangent has an equation like y=px+4.65. `p` is the slope. First we draw some lines with different values of `p`. A good interval is `-1.2,-1.1,...,-0.8`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % u_1
    \node (h) at (1.5,4.2) {};
    \node (b) at (2.4,2.3) {};
    \node (j) at (4.4,1.6) {};
    \draw[very thin,name path=curve 1] plot[smooth,tension=0.9] 
          coordinates {(h) (b) (j)} node[right]{$u_{1}$};
    \coordinate[label=left:{\scriptsize$I_{0}$}] (i0) at (0,4.65);
 \foreach \p in {-1.2,-1.1,...,-0.8}
 {\draw[blue,very thin] (0,4.65) -- (5,5*\p+4.65);}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now we know that the slope is something like -1.0,...,-0.96

**Step 2**   With intersections we can find the better value :

I named `curve 2` and `curve 3` the lines defined by `y=-0.9828*x+4.65' and`y=-0.96*x+4.65' and I try to find the intersections of the curves with the curve 1. I found `-0.9828`with trials. With for example `-0.99` I get an error because the curves have no intersection.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % u_1
    \node (h) at (1.5,4.2) {};
    \node (b) at (2.4,2.3) {};
    \node (j) at (4.4,1.6) {};
    \draw[very thin,name path=curve 1] plot[smooth,tension=0.9] coordinates {(h) (b) (j)} node[right]{$u_{1}$};
    \coordinate[label=left:{\scriptsize$I_{0}$}] (i0) at (0,4.65);

 \draw[green,very thin,name path=curve 3] (0,4.65) -- (5,-5*0.96+4.65);
 \fill [name intersections={of=curve 1 and curve 3, name=i, total=\t}]
         [orange, opacity=0.5, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}]
        \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (2pt) node {}};  

 \draw[blue,very thin,name path=curve 2] (0,4.65) -- (5,-5*0.9828+4.65);
 \fill [name intersections={of=curve 1 and curve 2, name=i, total=\t}]
         [red, opacity=0.5, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}]
        \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (2pt) node {}};            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`p=-0.9828` seems to be a fine value.

**Step 3**

Now we know that the slope of the tangent to `u_0` is `-0.9828`. The tangent has for equation 
`y=-0.9828 *x +m`

You can draw several lines with different values of `m`. A good interval seems to be  m in  {5,5.5,...,7}

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % u_0
    \node (e) at (2.2,4.9) {};
    \node (f) at (3,3) {};
    \node (g) at (5,2.3) {};
    \draw[thick,name path=curve 4] plot[smooth,tension=0.9] coordinates {(e) (f) (g)} node[right]{$u_{0}$};     
\foreach \m in {5,5.5,...,7}
 {\draw[red,very thin] (0,\m) -- (5,-0.9828*5+\m);} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Step 4**  Now we know that m is very near 6.0. I added  `\def\m{5.9}`to modify this value easily . I name the curve `u_0` the `curve 4` and the line is named `curve 5`. I look at the intersections.

I use here only two values `m=6.2` and `m=5.9410``

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % u_0
    \node (e) at (2.2,4.9) {};
    \node (f) at (3,3) {};
    \node (g) at (5,2.3) {};
    \draw[thick,name path=curve 4] plot[smooth,tension=0.9] coordinates {(e) (f) (g)} node[right]{$u_{0}$};     

   \def\m{6.2}
  \draw[green,very thin,name path=curve 5] (0,\m) -- (5,-0.9828*5+\m);
 \fill [name intersections={of=curve 4 and curve 5, name=i, total=\t}]
         [orange, opacity=0.5, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}]
        \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (2pt) node {}};   

  \def\m{5.9410}
  \draw[red,very thin,name path=curve 5] (0,\m) -- (5,-0.9828*5+\m);
 \fill [name intersections={of=curve 4 and curve 5, name=i, total=\t}]
         [red, opacity=0.5, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}]
        \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (2pt) node {}};    

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Final Step**

Finally I take p=-0.992 and m=5.941 and the result is :

(I used a clip to limit the lines like you want)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % axes
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
    \draw (origin) -- (0,6.5) node[left]{$x_{2}$};
    \draw (origin) -- (9.5,0) node[below]{$x_{1}$};
    % u_0
    \node (e) at (2.2,4.9) {};
    \node (f) at (3,3) {};
    \node (g) at (5,2.3) {};
    \draw[thick] plot[smooth,tension=0.9] coordinates {(e) (f) (g)} node[right]{$u_{0}$};
    % u_1
    \node (h) at (1.5,4.2) {};
    \node (b) at (2.4,2.3) {};
    \node (j) at (4.4,1.6) {};
    \draw[thick] plot[smooth,tension=0.9] coordinates {(h) (b) (j)} node[right]{$u_{1}$};
    % first budget line (I_0 to p_0)
    \coordinate[label=left:{\scriptsize$I_{0}$}] (i0) at (0,4.65);
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (8,7) ;
    \draw[blue,very thin] (0,4.65) -- (7,-7*0.9828+4.65); 
    % second budget line (I_0 to p_1)
    \draw[red,very thin] (0,5.9410) -- (7,-0.9828*7+5.9410);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So how do I know which of the slopes is the "right" one? Should I count the lines or something like that? What I am saying is: tikz itself doesn't know it reached the curve, right, I must after drawing the picture figure out which of the lines is better? I think this is better than what I have, but I was hoping for something even better. To be honest, I thought one of your packages would have an easy solution for this...

Comment: No sorry my packages can do only simple stuff ! I think that it's not possible with tikz and tex to do what you want. The better way is to use mathematica, maple or the free xcas. The difficult point is to calculate the distance between the line and the curve. And you don't know the polynomial expression of `u_1`! Now to choice the good slope, you use the "dichotomy" method. First you try with `{-1.2,-1.18,...,-0.9}` and then you reduce this set : {-0.995,-0.990} etc.

Comment: I updated the answer, now I use intersections library but you need to use trials and errors. The slope is different because here I take care of the line width. The last value before to get an error is -0.9828

Answer (score 4):

**(Major Update)**

Here is a solution that draws the required diagram. It should be used for a demonstration purpose (show the ideas in class for example). The result is

[image]

My code is a little heavy and inelegant. Some macros would make it better, but I was focusing on getting the task done. The code is:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[point/.style={fill=blue,circle,minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0pt}]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{0.2}

\draw[->] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x_1$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[left] {$x_2$};

\coordinate[point] (a) at (1,2);
\coordinate[point] (c) at (1.25,1.3);
\coordinate[point] (b) at (2,1);
\coordinate[point] (i) at (0,2.5);

\coordinate (v) at ($(c) - (i)$);

%This is a (quadratic) Bézier curve. You can use Tikz' Bézier curves and adjust the control points  to do the same.
\draw[thick,blue] let
            \p{a} = (a),
            \p{c} = (c),
            \p{b} = (b),
            \p{v1} = ($(c) - \k*(v)$),
            \p{v2} = ($(c) + \k*(v)$)
            in
            plot[domain=0:1,variable=\t,samples =20,smooth] ({(1-\t)^2*\x{a} + 2*(1-\t)*\t*\x{v1} + (\t)^2*\x{c}}, {(1-\t)^2*\y{a} + 2*(1-\t)*\t*\y{v1} + (\t)^2*\y{c}})
            plot[domain=0:1,variable=\t,samples =20,smooth] ({(1-\t)^2*\x{c} + 2*(1-\t)*\t*\x{v2} + (\t)^2*\x{b}}, {(1-\t)^2*\y{c} + 2*(1-\t)*\t*\y{v2} + (\t)^2*\y{b}});

\draw[red] let
            \p{i} = (i),
            \p{v} = (v)
            in
            (i) -- ++(${-\y{i}/\y{v}}*(v)$) coordinate[point];

\coordinate[point] (d) at (1.2,2.3);
\coordinate[point] (f) at (1.55,1.6);
\coordinate[point] (e) at (2.3,1.3);

\draw[thick,blue,dashed] let
            \p{d} = (d),
            \p{f} = (f),
            \p{e} = (e),
            \p{v1} = ($(f) - \k*(v)$),
            \p{v2} = ($(f) + \k*(v)$)
            in
            plot[domain=0:1,variable=\t,samples =20,smooth] ({(1-\t)^2*\x{d} + 2*(1-\t)*\t*\x{v1} + (\t)^2*\x{f}}, {(1-\t)^2*\y{d} + 2*(1-\t)*\t*\y{v1} + (\t)^2*\y{f}})
            plot[domain=0:1,variable=\t,samples =20,smooth] ({(1-\t)^2*\x{f} + 2*(1-\t)*\t*\x{v2} + (\t)^2*\x{e}}, {(1-\t)^2*\y{f} + 2*(1-\t)*\t*\y{v2} + (\t)^2*\y{e}});

\draw[dashed,red] let
            \p{f} = (f),
            \p{v} = (v)
            in
            ($(f) + {-\x{f}/\x{v}}*(v)$) coordinate[point]  -- ($(f) + {-\y{f}/\y{v}}*(v)$) coordinate[point];

\draw[green] let
            \p{i} = (i),
            \p{f} = (f),
            \p{w} = ($(f) - (i)$)
            in
            (i) -- ++(${-\y{i}/\y{w}}*(\p{w})$) coordinate[point];


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**(Initial Answer)**

As I mentioned in my comment, the package tkz-fct computes tangents, you can check the documentation, there are good examples. It uses Gnuplot. As I don't have Gnuplot I could not build an example for you.

What follows is another approach, using the `intersections` library.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (2,2);
\coordinate (c) at (4,1);

\draw[name path=curve,smooth] plot coordinates {(a) (b) (c)};
\path[name path= circle] (b) circle[radius=1pt];

\draw[red, name intersections={of=curve and circle},shorten <=-2cm,shorten >=-2cm]
    (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Setting a smaller circle radius will give a more precise result.

As you can see, my solution uses `shorten`. A possible way around this is to use  intersections a second time to find where the points must be along the axis lines.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how would you know that the point of intersection of the tangent is `(b)`? I believe in the question you are only given a curve and an external point. You are not given the point on the curve on which the tangent goes through the given point.  I believe that this solution requires knowledge of the point on the curve.

Comment: It was my understanding that the tangents in the question were drawn by trial and error. In addition, the curves were drawn as plots from known points. My approach is to choose one of the points and draw the tangent there.

Comment: Thank you Peter. Rereading the question, I see that my answer does not completely answer the question, as the tangent is to be parallel to another (given) line.

Comment: @Frédéric, my problem is exactly that I don't want to specify the tangent point. I did that for some of the other figures, but then when I need to change the slope of the straight line (the budget line), that tangent point is not going to work again, and I need to once more look for a "tangent" point that works...

Comment: Very good update. Interesting approach !

Answer (score 0):

My try of using the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tzhelplines[step=.5](10,7)
\tzaxes*(9.5,7){$x_1$}[b]{$x_2$}[l]
% budget lines
\tzcoors(0,4.65)(A)(4.67,0)(B)(8.1,0)(C);
\tzline[black]"bgtA"(A)(B)
\tzline[blue]"bgtB"(A)(C)
% getting ready for curves
\tzanglemark[draw=none](A)(B)(C)
\def\sA{\tzangleresult}
\tzanglemark[draw=none](A)(C)($(C)+(1,0)$)
\def\sB{\tzangleresult}
% u_0
\tzvXpointat*{bgtA}{2.5}(X)
\tzcoors($(X)!2cm!-20:(A)$)(XL)
        ($(X)!2cm! 20:(B)$)(XR);
\tzplotcurve[thick](XL)(X)(XR){$u_0$}[-90];
% u_1
\tzvXpointat*{bgtB}{3.5}(Y)
\tzcoors($(Y)!2cm!-20:(A)$)(YL)
        ($(Y)!2cm! 15:(C)$)(YR);
\tztos[thick]"U1"(YL)[out=-70,in=\sB](Y)[out=\sB-180,in=175](YR){$u_1$}[r];
% dashed line
\tzvXpointat*{U1}{2.8}(K)
\clip (0,0) rectangle (7,6);
\tzLFn[red,densely dashed](K){-4.65/4.67}[0:6]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```