# How to get the intersection nodes of 2 arbitrary curves?

Tags: pstricks

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`pst-intersect`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-intersect)

In my experience, there is no macro in PSTricks to get the intersection nodes of two curves. Is it possible to do this in PSTricks? Or Am I am dreaming an impossible thing?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,3)
    \pscurve[linecolor=red](0,3)(1,1)(2,3)(3,2)(4,0)
    \pscurve[linecolor=blue](0,0)(1,3)(2,1)(3,1)(4,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Anything that can be done by TikZ can also be done by PSTricks. However, the reverse is not necessarily correct.

Comment: Seems appropriate that you get a `tikz` solution to your `PSTricks` question given your history :)

Comment: convert both `\pscurve` to `pathforall` and then compare both values. PSTricks has some other examples for `pathforall`, so you can see how it works.

Comment: @CodeMocker Your first statement is incorrect.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Why?

Comment: @CodeMocker Example: PSTricks can not calculate the bounding box of a PostScript graphic and transmit this result to (La)TeX.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: It can be done by multiple compilation theoretically --- the first run saves the intermediate data to a temporary file and it will be updated for the next run until it converges to a stable value --- but I have not done it yet.

Comment: @CodeMocker So, your first statement is _theoretically_ correct... but not _practically_ ! (And for your second sentence, it is the opposite!)

Comment: @PaulGaborit: I am trying to prove that my first and second postulates are practically and theoretically correct. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just released a new PSTricks package [`pst-intersect`](https://github.com/cbersch/pst-intersect), which can calculate the intersections of almost arbitrary paths.

Concerning your curves, you can calculate the intersections as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido, pst-intersect}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,3)
  \pssavepath[linecolor=red]{A}{\pscurve(0,3)(1,1)(2,3)(3,2)(4,0)}
  \pssavepath[linecolor=blue]{B}{\pscurve(0,0)(1,3)(2,1)(3,1)(4,3)}
  \psintersect[showpoints, name=C]{A}{B}
  \pstracecurve[linewidth=2\pslinewidth, istart=2, istop=3]{C}{A}
  \multido{\i=1+1}{3}{\uput[0](C\i){\i}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

With the result

[image]

This also shows some other package features: Using the intersection nodes, and retracing parts of saved paths.

In order to get the coordinates of the intersection nodes, you can either use `pst-nodes`'s parameter `saveNodeCoors`, or the package macro `\psGetIsectCenter` (both options available since version 0.3). The values can then be shown with `\psPrintValue` of the `pst-tools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido, pst-intersect, pst-tools}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,3)
  \pssavepath[linecolor=red]{A}{\pscurve(0,3)(1,1)(2,3)(3,2)(4,0)}
  \pssavepath[linecolor=blue]{B}{\pscurve(0,0)(1,3)(2,1)(3,1)(4,3)}
  \psintersect[showpoints, name=C, saveNodeCoors]{A}{B}
  \pstracecurve[linewidth=2\pslinewidth, istart=2, istop=3]{C}{A}
  \multido{\i=1+1}{3}{\uput[0](C\i){\i}}
\end{pspicture}

\bigskip

\makebox[4em]{X} \makebox[4em]{Y}\\
\multido{\i=1+1}{3}{%
  \makebox[4em]{\psPrintValue{N-C\i.x}}
  \makebox[4em]{\psPrintValue{N-C\i.y}}\\
}%

\makebox[4em]{X} \makebox[4em]{Y}\\
\multido{\i=1+1}{3}{%
  \makebox[4em]{\psPrintValue{\psGetIsectCenter{C}{}{\i} I-C\i.x}}
  \makebox[4em]{\psPrintValue{\psGetIsectCenter{C}{}{\i} I-C\i.y}}\\
}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we refer to each intersection point by name for later use such as putting a label at that point?

Comment: I updated the answer to show some features and the new syntax for the newly released package (will appear soon on CTAN).

Comment: Is it possible to get the coordinates of the intersection points?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg All the coordinates are stored on the Postscript level in an array `Points` inside the dictionary `PIT@<name>` that belongs to the intersection. For the above example, you can see it e.g. by putting `\makeatletter\PIT@Verb{ PIT@C /Points get == }\makeatother` somewhere after the `\psintersect` call.

Comment: @Christoph Can I make you give an example og this? I can't make it work.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I added an example to the answer, hope that helps.

Comment: There is a typo in the first page of the documentation. `pst-optexp` should be  changed to `pst-intersect`.

Comment: When will v0.3 be on CTAN?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I submitted it this night. You can also get it from https://github.com/cbersch/pst-intersect/archive/0.3.zip Maybe I was too fast to update the answer ;)

Comment: Thank you; I'll use the GitHub code and wait for CTAN to be updated. `:)`

Answer (score 15):

Here's how this could be done with TikZ using the `intersections` library:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red, smooth, name path=first] plot coordinates {(0,3)(1,1)(2,3)(3,2)(4,0)};
    \draw [blue, smooth, name path=second] plot coordinates {(0,0)(1,3)(2,1)(3,1)(4,3)};
    \draw [thick, name intersections={of=first and second, total=\n}]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}{
            (intersection-\i) circle [radius=3pt]
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Thank you very much for answering. Unfortunately no bounty for TikZ solution. :-)

Comment: show it with the same coordinates as in the above example ... ;-)

Comment: @Herbert: "Please"... `;-)`

Comment: Your comment does not get enough attention [in this link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37866/how-to-draw-tangent-vectors-and-component-vectors-on-a-curve?lq=1#comment236908_37890).

Comment: @Yake: but your curves look fare different. You know, that you have no equivalent function in tikZ for `\pscurce`... ;-)

Comment: @Herbert: Ah, that's what you mean. Why didn't you say that directly? You may be right that there's no equivalent function in TikZ for `\pscurve`, I don't know, because I don't know what `\pscurve` does exactly. That's beside the point of mozartstraße's question though, the question was about finding the intersections of arbitrary paths.

Comment: @mozartstraße: I think it would be best if you leave the answer unaccepted. That way, it's more likely for someone to notice that the issue is still unsolved for PSTricks, and maybe they will come up with a solution. Thanks for the bounty, though =)

Comment: No problem. I am tired of waiting for the PSTricks solutions. :-)