# How to draw vector fields along a curve with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I've drawn a smooth curve from a point *p* to a point *q* using the package tikz.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (0,0) to [out=-20, in=170] (8,0);
\filldraw[black] (0,0)circle(1.5pt)  node[anchor = east]{$p$};
\filldraw[black] (8,0)circle(1.5pt)  node[anchor = west]{$q$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Now I would like to draw 2 different vector fields along my curve:

- the velocity vector field of the curve, i.e. a tangent vector field of constant length;
- another vector fields which is orthogonal with the curve at every point, and it has increasing length. More precisely, it has zero length at the starting point *p* and it has unitary length at the end point *q*.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Related [How to draw tangent vectors and component vectors on a curve](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37866/how-to-draw-tangent-vectors-and-component-vectors-on-a-curve).

Comment: @salimbou thank you for the link! The second code of the first answer seems what I am looking for, more or less. But I can't control the curve.. I tried playing a bit with the parameters but I can't get any reasonable result. I would like a curve which does not bend too much. It should be something just "slightly" curved.

Comment: Ok, I solved my problem! :)