# Drawing two vectors at a precise point of a curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I have drawn the following figure.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}      
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
\edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
\edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (0,0) to [bend left=20]  coordinate[pos=0.15](A)(7,2);
\filldraw[black] coordinate[pos=1] (B)(7,2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[thick,gray] (A) to [bend right = 10] (7,2);
\gettikzxy{(A)}{\ax}{\ay}
\gettikzxy{(B)}{\bx}{\by}
\fill[black] (\ax, \ay) circle (1.5pt) node[anchor = east]{$\sigma(\epsilon)$};
\fill[black] (\bx, \by) circle (1.5pt) node[anchor = east]{$p$};
\fill[black] (7,2) circle (1.5pt) node[anchor = west]{$q$};


\draw (3.6,1.8) node[anchor = south]{$\sigma$};
\draw (4,1) node[anchor = south]{$\delta$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
```

Here is the image.

[image]
Now I would like to add two vectors at the point `$\sigma(\epsilon)$`, one tangent to the curve `$\sigma$` and the other one tangent to the curve `$\delta$`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does it helps? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37866/how-to-draw-tangent-vectors-and-component-vectors-on-a-curve?rq=1 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25940/1952

Comment: @Ignasi - I don't think it's quite a duplicate, because OP wants the tangent at delta drawn at sigma (at least I think that's what the question asks).  In Metapost you could just use `rotated angle direction t of curve` to get the desired angle, but I don't see how you can do that with a Tikzy decoration approach.

Comment: @Thruston I don't say it's a duplicate, but a related question which, may be, it's worth to read.

Comment: @Ignasi - fair enough!

Comment: I'm trying to "play" with the codes I found in the links.. but I am not getting anything good so far. I am very new to the package Tikz. I've discovered it just yesterday.. 
Anyhow thank you for the links!

Comment: @Onil90 A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution playing a bit with the codes I found in the answer at  [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37866/how-to-draw-tangent-vectors-and-component-vectors-on-a-curve?rq=1), as it was suggested in the comments.

I do not have any idea why and how the code does work, but still the result is exactly what I was looking for. I want to share with you the code because maybe it will be useful for some other people one day.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}      
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}



\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
\edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
\edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (0,0) to [bend left=20]node[sloped,inner sep=0cm,above,pos=.15,
  anchor=south west,
  minimum height=(10.5)*0.3cm,minimum width=(10.5)*.3cm](N){}  coordinate[pos=0.15,sloped,inner sep=0cm,below,
  anchor=south west,
  minimum height=3cm, minimum  width=2cm] (A)(8,2);

\path (N.south west)           
       edge[-stealth',black] node[above] {$\dot{\sigma}(\epsilon)$} (N.south east);


\filldraw[black] coordinate[pos=1] (B)(8,2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[thick,gray] (A) to[bend right = 15] node[sloped,inner sep=0cm,above,pos=0,
  anchor=south west,
  minimum height=(10.5)*0.3cm,minimum width=(10.5)*.3cm](C){}  (8,2);

\path (C.south west)
       edge[-stealth',black] node[below] {$\dot{\delta}(0)$} (C.south east);      

\gettikzxy{(A)}{\ax}{\ay}
\gettikzxy{(B)}{\bx}{\by}
\fill[black] (\ax, \ay) circle (1.5pt) node[anchor = east]{$\sigma(\epsilon) = \delta(0)$};
\fill[black] (\bx, \by) circle (1.5pt) node[anchor = east]{$p$};
\fill[black] (8,2) circle (1.5pt) node[anchor = west]{$q$};


\draw (5,2) node[anchor = south]{$\sigma$};
\draw (5.5,1) node[anchor = south]{$\delta$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Here is the picture of the result.

[image]

Comment: where is defined `\gettikzxy`, `\ax`, `ay`, ... your example I can't compile. do I miss something?

Comment: ah yeah! sorry! it is incomplete! I will edit in few seconds

Comment: Now it should work!

Comment: now it works! (+1) for nice solution  :-)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a decoration but not the `markings` decoration as that will prove to be too inaccurate. Instead, the `show path construction` decoration can be used in combination with the basic layer `\pgftransformcurveattime` command. It isn't strictly necessary to access the internal segment points from the decoration engine, but it is less verbose.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{mark curve vector/.style args={at (#1) with #2}{
  postaction={decorate, decoration={show path construction,
    curveto code={\pgfslopedattimetrue\pgfallowupsidedownattimetrue%
      \pgftransformcurveattime{#1}{\pgf@decorate@inputsegment@first}%
        {\pgf@decorate@inputsegment@supporta}%
        {\pgf@decorate@inputsegment@supportb}%
        {\pgf@decorate@inputsegment@last}%
        #2}}}}}   
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [draw=gray, thick, mark curve vector=at (0.15) with { 
    \draw [black, -stealth, thin] coordinate (A) (0,0) -- (2,0)
      node [midway, above left] {$\dot\sigma(\epsilon)$}; 
  }] 
  (0,0) coordinate (p) to [bend left=20] 
    node [pos=2/3, above] {$\sigma$} (7,2) coordinate (q);

\draw [draw=gray, thick, mark curve vector=at (0) with { 
     \draw [black, -stealth, thin]  (0,0) -- (2,0)
        node [midway, below] {$\dot\delta(0)$}; 
  }] (A) to [bend right=15] node [pos=2/3, above] {$\delta$} (q);

\fill (p) circle [radius=0.05] node [left] {$p$};
\fill (q) circle [radius=0.05] node [right] {$q$};
\fill (A) circle [radius=0.05] node [above left] 
  {$\sigma(\epsilon)=\delta(0)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]