# Put node on ellipse in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make a simple drawing in tikz consisting of:

- An ellipse
- Some label inside the ellipse
- Another label near the curve
- An outer normal vector to the ellipse, again with a label

Producing the ellipse and the first two labels is no problem. However, I can't figure out how to put a node on the boundary of the ellipse. How to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \filldraw[fill=black!20!white](0, 0) ellipse (100pt and 50pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please supply how you draw the ellipse (i.e. a MWE), is the ellipse a node, or a manual `\draw` command, for instance?

Comment: @zeroth: currently I produce the ellipse with `\filldraw[fill=black!20!white](0, 0) ellipse (100pt and 50pt)`

Comment: Please add that to the question (with a full `\documentclass ... \usepackage` it will make it a lot easier for people to supply an answer), i.e. no need to re-create an ellipse. Kind regards and thanks! :)

Comment: @zeroth: added the info. Please note that I'm not having trouble with errors or bugs, but need help using TikZ

Comment: I am well aware of that. :) Thanks for supplying it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For drawing the normal vector, you can use the approach described in [How to draw tangent line of an arbitrary point on a path in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz). It allows you to type

```
\filldraw[fill=black!20!white, tangent=0.1](0, 0) ellipse (100pt and 50pt);
\draw [blue, ultra thick, use tangent, -latex] (0,0) -- (0,-2) node [pos=0.5, anchor=east] {Normal vector};
```

to get:

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    tangent/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,% switch on markings
            mark=
                at position #1
                with
                {
                    \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
                }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    use tangent/.style={
        shift=(tangent point-#1),
        x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
        y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
    },
    use tangent/.default=1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=black!20!white, tangent=0.1](0, 0) ellipse (100pt and 50pt);
\draw [blue, ultra thick, use tangent, -latex] (0,0) -- (0,-2) node [pos=0.5, anchor=east] {Normal vector};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```