# tikz - drawing an edge that splits to reach two targets

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using tikz and want to have an arrow from one node that leaves and goes straight for a while and then splits into two arrows going to different nodes.

Here is a picture I drew a while ago.  I now want to replace it with a tikz figure:[image]

Notice that one of the vertical edges goes straight for a while and splits into 2.  Is there a way to do this cleanly?  Let's say that the source is named `source` and the targets are named `targetA` and `targetB`.

I could specify the in and out angles so that they come out of `source` with the same slope, but I really want them to be the same edge for a while, not just be close to each other.

Bonus: is there an easy way to make the edge dashed while it overlaps a box to give the impression it's going behind the box?

Comment: Since *you are using Tikz* show us please what you had done.

Comment: Is the shared portion of the path always a straight line or could it be curved as well?

Comment: To get a smooth transition from the common, straight section to the split curved section, you will need to calculate the angle (slope) of the straight section using \pgfmathparse and atan() or atan2()().

Comment: @PaulGessler  It will be a straight line

Comment: Related: [Typesetting a directed hypergraph in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108064/typesetting-a-directed-hypergraph-in-tikz/108079#108079)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP did not put any effort in this question in the past 23 months, and probably will never do.