# How draw lines at certain angle on a function graph in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

How can one draw orthogonal tick marks on a function? For instance in the following plot I would like to make orthogonal tick marks on the function `y=x^2`, say.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
      \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$y$};
      \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{\x*\x});
      \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,smooth,variable=\y,red]  plot ({\y*\y},{\y});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I kind of know it will involve `\foreach`, but I am not sure how to proceed.

To make things clear, I would like to have the tick marks "following" the graph of the function. Also if there are two or more functions on the same plot, then each should have a separate option for decoration. Please see comments below.

Comment: What do you mean by "orthogonal tikz"?

Comment: Lines/arrows that are at 90 degrees angle to the graph. Of course a more general degree angle is better, but 90 degrees is OK too.

Comment: Take a look at [How to draw tangent line of an arbitrary point on a path in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz)

Comment: @LoveLearning: if the answer Jake linked helped you we might consider to close this question as a duplicate. Do you agree?

Comment: I expected a better answer of the type: Let y be a function of x, i.e. y=f(x) then; 

\foreach x on the graph of "f" draw a vector at angle \theta with spacing S between the vectors.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @LoveLearning: I'm still confused what you mean by "tikz". TikZ is the name of the graphics framework that PGFPlots uses, but that doesn't seem to be what you mean.

Comment: I mean some kind of markings, such as a stright line segment, a "tik". My bad I admit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `markings` `decoration` for this.

Note that, for some reason, this doesn't work with the `smooth` option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark={
            between positions 0 and 1 step 0.4cm
            with {\draw (0,-1mm) -- (0,1mm);}
        }}
    ]
      \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
      \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$y$};
      \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,blue, postaction=decorate] plot ({\x},{\x*\x});
      \draw[scale=0.5,domain=-3:3,variable=\y,red, postaction=decorate]  plot ({\y*\y},{\y});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such an elegant solutions Jake, thank you very much!

Comment: Do you think it is possible with two different styles/types of decoration (one for each line, say) in the same graph?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. What styles were you thinking of?

Comment: Similar to the one above but when I change you code to: `between positions 0 and 1 step 0.4cm
            with {\draw (0,0mm) -- (0,1mm);}`

then this applies to both lines. It would be nice if this only applied to one of the line and then for the other line we would have something like:

`between positions 0 and 1 step 0.4cm
            with {\draw (0,0) -- (0,-1mm);}`

Notice the -1mm in the second parenthesis.

Comment: @LoveLearning Add the `decoration` style to each `\draw` commands.

Comment: Could you please show what you mean more explicitly @HarishKumar?

Comment: Some thing like `\draw[scale=0.5,
        domain=-3:3,
        blue,
        decoration={
        markings,
        mark={
            between positions 0 and 1 step 0.4cm
            with {\draw (0,-1mm) -- (0,1mm);}
        }},
        postaction=decorate] plot ({\x},{\x*\x});` and change what you want.

Comment: @LoveLearning: That will be a duplicate. `\draw[scale=0.5, domain=-3:3, variable=\x,blue, decoration={ markings, mark={ between positions 0 and 1 step 0.4cm with {\draw (0,0) -- (0,1mm);} }}, postaction=decorate] plot ({\x},{\x*\x});` and `\draw[scale=0.5, domain=-3:3, variable=\y,red, decoration={ markings, mark={ between positions 0 and 1 step 0.4cm with {\draw (0,0) -- (0,-1mm);} }}, postaction=decorate]  plot ({\y*\y},{\y});` should do what you want. Remove the options for `tikzpicture` of course.

Comment: It worked great the way you described it. I want to give you the solution credit. Thanks for the help.