# Error when adding arrows along 3d parametric curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to create a 3-D parametric curve using TikZ. I also want to add decoration arrows along the curve. However, I'm getting an error message saying the dimension is too large. So is there any way to get rid of the error message? Below is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs, mathtools, commath}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\definecolor{CPgreen}{RGB}{21, 71, 52}
\definecolor{CPgold}{RGB}{198, 146, 20}
\definecolor{Sealgray}{RGB}{84, 88, 90}
\definecolor{Skyblue}{RGB}{181, 227, 216}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
        line cap =round,>=latex,line width=0.5pt,font=\scriptsize]
        
        \node (O) at (0,0,0) {};
        \draw[->] (O.center) -- (4,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
        \draw[->] (O.center) -- (0,3.75,0) node[anchor=west]{$y$};
        \draw[->] (O.center) -- (0,0,3.75) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

        \begin{scope}[decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position 0.15 with {\arrow{>}},
                mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}},
                mark=at position 0.85 with {\arrow{>}}}]
            \draw[postaction={decorate},line width = 0.825,color=CPgold] plot [variable=\t, domain=0:2*pi, samples=100, smooth] 
            ({2*cos(deg(\t))},{1.5*sin(deg(\t))},{\t-1});
        \end{scope}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The decoration arrows work if I use PGF instead, but PGF's axis does not align with mine.

Here is the Overleaf link: https://www.overleaf.com/4452138147qnvxcwtxmgbn

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There is no error if you remove the `smooth` option (see for instance [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170595/73317); `pre length` and `post length` don't seem to help here, however).

Comment: It never occurred to me to change that; thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I was surprised the first time I saw this too! :)