# Warning about size for plot with decoration in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, warnings

I am plotting some functions, and putting a ">" decoration on them. This generally works, but in one case it gives a warning

> I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
> Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

The same plot without the decoration instructions does not give any warning. I changed the line width and color so that the second line is visible above the first.

The warning does not stop the compilation, but I'd like to know what's wrong, and correct it if possible.

Here is a MWE of the "problem".

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,yscale=1]

% causes the warning 
% I can't work with sizes bigger than 
% about 19 feet.
% Continue and I'll use the largest value 
% I can.
\draw[domain=1:2.297, smooth, variable=\x,line
width=1.5,decoration={markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}] plot ({\x}, {4/\x^(5/3)});

% draws the same function as above, 
% with no decoration. Causes no warning
% The different line width and color do not
% affect the problem
\draw[domain=1:2.297, smooth, variable=\x,line
width=0.5,yellow] plot ({\x}, {4/\x^(5/3)});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE. Try to replace `smooth` with `samples=101`-

Comment: Hi, that worked! Thanks! But I'm not entirely clear why...

Comment: Option `smooth` use spline functions. Their calculation may cause problems, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is the same question, but I can not make the given solution by @percusse work here. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170595/tikz-decorations-markings-cause-dimension-too-large