# Add a second label to a path in an automaton

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

Friends, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,,node distance=4cm,on grid,auto, /tikz/initial text={start}]
\node[state, initial, accepting] (q0) {0};
\node[state] (q1) [right=of q0] {1};
\path[->] (q0) edge [bend left] node {on} (q1)
           (q1) edge [bend left] node {off} (q0)
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following output:

[image: Automaton]

Pretty straightforward, I guess. `:)` I was wondering if it would be possible to add a second label to each one of those paths in a way I don't need to calculate their coordinates and hardcode them into the picture. My idea for a second label would is to put the text in the opposite direction of the primary label. `:)`

As a bonus, I was wondering how challenging would be to make the second label a little different than the first one, say, like this gimp'ed image:

[image: Second image]

Any hints on how to achieve this? `:)` I am already happy if a second label is possible, even without these bells and whistles.

Comment: I'm not sure if this suffices your demands, but you could just specify a second node with [above] or below the path. This wouldn't be totally automatic but far away from hardcoded. Yor path would look like this: `\path[->] (q0) edge [bend left] node[above] {on} node[below] {a} (q1) (q1) edge [bend left] node[below] {off} node[above] {a} (q0);` This produces the two `a` nodes on the inner sides of the edges.

Comment: @Dave: silly me, I had no idea of using a `node` (living and learning)! Perhaps you could convert your comment to an answer? I think it's a valid approach towards solving my question (of course, it's up to you). Thank you! **Edit:** actually, one the answers use this very approach, oopsie. But I really appreciate your comment! `:)`

Comment: I simply forgot to check this here since I had to do some work yesterday. I'm glad you got your answer anyway :)

Comment: @Dave: thank you for the initial insight! `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another idea, using `pic` (requires PGF 3.0.0)

The code which draws the "status" (on/off), and the additional char (a), and the little arrow, is all encapsulated in a `pic` style, which gets as two arguments the text to show in the "status" and in the "char". We need in fact two different `pic`s, depending on the relative position of "status" and "char".

Defining pics with two arguments is a little more complex than single-argument pics, because the shortcut `foo/.pic` allows only for a single argument. So we have to go the "low level" `pics/foo/.style`, but still it is very straightforward:

```
\tikzset{
  pics/second label below/.style 2 args = {
   code = {
    \node[above] (-status) {#1};
    \node[below=3mm, inner sep=1pt] (-char) {\small #2};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (-char);
    }
  },
  pics/second label above/.style 2 args = {
   code = {
    \node[below] (-status) {#1};
    \node[above=3mm, inner sep=1pt] (-char) {\small #2};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (-char);
    }
  }
}
```

This pic can be used like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,,node distance=4cm,on grid,auto, /tikz/initial text={start}]
\node[state, initial, accepting] (q0) {0};
\node[state] (q1) [right=of q0] {1};
\path[->] (q0) edge [bend left] pic {second label below={on}{a}} (q1)
           (q1) edge [bend left] pic {second label above={off}{a}} (q0)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And produces:

[image: Result]

As a bonus, it can be used at other positions of the curve, and it works too:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,,node distance=4cm,on grid,auto, /tikz/initial text={start}]
\node[state, initial, accepting] (q0) {0};
\node[state] (q1) [right=of q0] {1};
\path[->] (q0) edge [bend left] pic[pos=0.8] {second label below={on}{a}} (q1)
           (q1) edge [bend left] pic[pos=0.8] {second label above={off}{a}} (q0)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Oh my, this is truly awesome! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `swap` or the shorthand `'` to put the second label in the opposite direction of the first one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,,node distance=4cm,on grid,auto, /tikz/initial text={start}]
\node[state, initial, accepting] (q0) {0};
\node[state] (q1) [right=of q0] {1};
\path[->] (q0) edge [bend left] node {on} node [swap] {a} (q1)
          (q1) edge [bend left] node {off} node [swap] {a} (q0)
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe you can enlarge the `outer sep` to shift the second node:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,,node distance=4cm,on grid,auto, /tikz/initial text={start},
    secn/.style={swap,outer sep=5pt}
]
\node[state, initial, accepting] (q0) {0};
\node[state] (q1) [right=of q0] {1};
\path[->] (q0) edge [bend left] node {on}node[secn]{a} (q1)
          (q1) edge [bend left] node {off}node[secn]{a} (q0)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: How nice, I had no idea there was a `swap` option!

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is use of `label distance=xxcm` and `below/above:text`, as displayed below.  In the direction from `q0` to `q1` the label a is allocated below of the path, hence the key `below` is used, actually, `left`, `right`, `above right` and more can be an option too.  Utilizing the same idea, the path from `q1` to `q0` the label a is above the path, hence the key `above` is used.

```
node[label={[label distance=0.5cm] below:a}]
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,,node distance=4cm,on grid,auto, /tikz/initial text={start}]
\node[state, initial, accepting] (q0) {0};
\node[state] (q1) [right=of q0] {1};
\path[->] (q0) edge [bend left] 
node[label={[label distance=0.5cm] below:a}] {on} (q1)
          (q1) edge [bend left] 
node[label={[label distance=0.5cm] above:a}] {off} (q0)
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh my, it looks very interesting! Thank you! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

As none of the existing answers show how to draw the little arrowed paths tangent to the curved ones, let me stole some code from Jake, namely: [How to draw tangent line of an arbitrary point on a path in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz/25940#25940).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}% we need this library
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{tangent/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,% switch on markings
            mark=
                at position #1
                with
                {
                    \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
                }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    use tangent/.style={
        shift=(tangent point-#1),
        x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
        y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
    },
    use tangent/.default=1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=4cm,on grid,auto, /tikz/initial text={start}]
\node[state, initial, accepting] (q0) {0};
\node[state] (q1) [right=of q0] {1};

\path[->] (q0) edge [bend left,tangent=0.5] node {on} (q1);
\draw[->, thick, use tangent] (0,0) --++ (0,-0.25) node[below]{a};

\path[->] (q1) edge [bend left,tangent=0.5] node {off} (q0);
\draw[->, thick, use tangent] (0,0) --++ (0,-0.25) node[above]{a};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: ooh TikZ magic going on! Grazie, Claudio! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: you're always welcome! I've seen Brazil managed to win the first match in World Cup.. though the penalty was too generous `;)`

Comment: egreg and I were talking in the chatroom that, given the past penalty shootouts, we were likely to miss that one (Neymar almost missed it). `:)` It wasn't a penalty at all, thankfully Oscar scored the 3rd goal. `:)` I am waiting for the big game on Saturday. Avanti, Azzurra! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

With minimal modification, using the `pin` option

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,,node distance=4cm,on grid,auto, /tikz/initial text={start},
pin edge={bend left=0,black, thick},
pin distance=3mm,
every pin/.style={font=\small, inner sep=1pt},
point/.style={inner sep=0, outer sep=0, minimum size=0}
]
\node[state, initial, accepting] (q0) {0};
\node[state] (q1) [right=of q0] {1};
\path[->] (q0) edge [bend left] node[pos=.3] {on} node[point,pin=below:a,pos=.2] {} (q1)
           (q1) edge [bend left] node {off} node[point,pin=above:b] {} (q0)
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you vary the value of `pos` you can shift the pin along the path and the arrow will follow it.

[image: preview]

Comment: Does anybody know why using `coordinate` instead of `node[point]` results in a double arrow for the pin?

Comment: Oh my, another neat trick! Thank you! `:)`