# Draw a curve in TikZ with hairs growing on one side

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to be able to draw tikz pictures that generalize the following one:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to (1,0);
\foreach \n in {.1,.2,...,.9} \draw (\n,0) to (\n,.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result of the above code is a horizontal line with short "hairs" growing off one side, perpendicular to the curve.  I want to achieve this effect but for curves that bend in customized ways, for example by specifying a number of points they pass through along with in and out angles at each one.  In that case, I can't just repeat the above strategy, since the exact endpoints of the hairs are determined in a complicated way by the points and in/out angles used to define the curve.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shamelessly using [this great tangent line answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25940/19372) to sort out your problem. Try the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    tangent/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {
      \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
      \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
      \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
      }},postaction=decorate},
    use tangent/.style={
        shift=(tangent point-#1),
        x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
        y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
    },
    use tangent/.default=1
]
% Define your path here
\def\PTH{(0,0) to [out=20,in=120] (5,2) to [out=-60, in=110] (9,1)}
% Choose the number of "hairs" here
\def\tans{30}
\draw \PTH;
\foreach \x in {1,...,\tans}{
  \path[tangent=\x/\tans] \PTH;
  \draw [blue, thick, use tangent=1] (0,0) -- (0,.5);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This should give you the following picture:

[image]

Note that you can change the length of the "hairs," which are now set to 0.5 in the `foreach` loop. Also, if you change the endpoint of the "hairs" to be `(.5,0)` instead, then you will get short hairs that are tangent to the path.