# Parallel Transport on a Hyperbola

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, diagrams, asymptote

**Disclaimer:** *I'm very new to fancy TeX pictures..as you can see by my reputation 1 on this exchange.*

---

I recently came across [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339301/draw-tangent-vectors-of-a-path-on-a-sphere), describing how to the draw parallel transport of a vector on a sphere.  For a paper I'm writing, I'd like to do the same on the upper-sheet of a hyperboloid, but I have absolutely no idea how to do this beyond [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359902/simple-tikz-hyperbola) showing how to draw a hyperboloid in LaTeX.

In short, how can I code up this picture

[image]

where:

- The blue thing is supposed to be a hyperboloid of one sheet
- The red squares are supposed to be parts of tangent spaces at two points in the hyperboloid
- The green arrows are supposed to be orthogonal vectors
- The brown line is supposed to be a curve travelling along the hyperboloid

*So far I have the following (terrible) attempt...*

```
\begin{asy}
import graph3;
unitsize(1cm);

% Setup
settings.render=0;
settings.prc=false;

size3(25);

% Hyperboloid
triple f(pair t){return (sinh(t.y)*cos(t.x)/2,sinh(t.y)*sin(t.x)/2, cosh(t.y));}
surface s=surface(f,(0,-2) ,(2*pi,2),nu=40,nv=40,Spline);
draw(s,green+opacity(0.9),render(merge=true));

% Path
path3 circX=arc(sinh(t.y),sinh(t.y),4,normal=x);
\end{asy}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch Thanks for the warm welcome.  I added a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish in TeX. :)

Comment: Hi Mike!  Are you still struggling with the parallel transport?  I have some ideas about how to draw it; either I develop them or show them in a drawing, but... towards the end of the next week.  Anyway, in the second reference the hyperboloid is one sheet; in the drawing is only half of a two sheet.  What do you need?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to get a path, with vectors along it transporting (in parallel) the vectors from the bottom of the two-sheet hyperboloid (top component) to some point on it.  

But ya still struggling with it :p