# Scale a decoration in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

Let's suppose a drawing that uses a simple decoration (for illustration, let's say a simple spring):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2] %scale in question
\draw[decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}] 
    (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

The output without `scale`:

[image: without scale]

And with scale:

[image: with scale]

So yes, the line is scaled, but the decoration is not. Is there an option to scale a decoration?

The spring decoration is a minimal example, more interesting would be fancier decorations like `tangent` (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
tangent/.style={
    decoration={
        markings,% switch on markings
        mark=
        at position #1
        with
        {
            \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
            \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
            \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
        }
    },
    postaction=decorate
},
use tangent/.style={
    shift=(tangent point-#1),
    x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
    y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
},
use tangent/.default=1
]
\draw [tangent=0.7] (0,0) to [out=90,in=100] (2,0);
\draw [blue, thick, use tangent, ->] (0,0) -- (-1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

creates the following output:

[image: tangent without scale]

Adding `scale=2`:

[image: tangent with scale]

Is there an option to avoid that?

Comment: In this particular case, you can wrap the whole `tikzpicture` in a `\scalebox{2}{...}`.  But I don't know if that suffices for your general need.

Comment: No because that also scales text, which would be bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Just the easy way:**

You can define a \myscale parameter and use it inside your figures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,shapes}

\begin{document}

\def\myscale{2}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale,
tangent/.style={
    decoration={
        markings,% switch on markings
        mark=
        at position #1
        with
        {
            \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
            \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
            \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
        }
    },
    postaction=decorate
},
use tangent/.style={
    shift=(tangent point-#1),
    x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
    y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
},
use tangent/.default=1
]
\draw [tangent=0.7] (0,0) to [out=90,in=100] (2,0);
\draw [blue, thick, use tangent, ->] (0,0) -- ({-1*\myscale},0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale] %scale in question
\draw[decorate,decoration={zigzag,
                                    pre length={0.3*\myscale cm},
                                    post length={0.3*\myscale cm},
                                    segment length={6*\myscale},
                                    amplitude={6*\myscale}}] 
    (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Rescale it to check results.

Comment: You have to avoid `shift` options to be sure it works ok... `xshift` and `yshift` is ok but `shift` will not be rescaled as you expect.

Comment: Good idea for a first solution.

Comment: You can expand it ... (At least I use it like this)... You can add an if statement (with as many branches as you think you need) to check scaling and select `\myfont` (for `\normalsize`, `\large` etc) or `\myfontsize`(for \fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont etc -With `anyfontsize` you can also just multiply font and bazelineskip by `\myscale` or use it as you wish-) parameter. This way the text gets rescaled too in your preferred way. I think you will not find another so easy solution because many options in tikz rescale and other doesn't... This means other way for any other shape options...