# Extending a tangent line until x and y axes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a graph that contains the following elements:

1. A downward-sloping curve in the northeast quadrant of a 2d Cartesian plane;
2. a line tangent to an arbitrary point on this curve; and
3. the tangent line extends to touch (but not cross) the x and y axes.

I managed to get points 1 and 2 done, but 3 cannot be done without a lot of manual adjustments.

## Question

Is there a more efficient way to extend the tangent line (the blue line in my MWE) to both axes? I was thinking, e.g. perhaps the vertical intercept could be determined through some version of the `(tangent point -| 0,0)` syntax?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    tangent/.style={ % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25940/18228
        decoration={
            markings,% switch on markings
            mark=
                at position #1
                with
                {
                    \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
                }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    use tangent/.style={
        shift=(tangent point-#1),
        x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
        y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
    },
    use tangent/.default=1
]
\draw[very thick,tangent=.4](.5,4)to[bend right=35](5.5,.5);
\draw[use tangent,blue](-2,0)--(2,0); % Better way to draw this line?
\draw[<->](0,5)node[left]{$y$}--(0,0)--(7,0)node[below]{$x$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: I think some tikz beginner tutorial does something like that. Is tikz-minimal? It shows how to calculate the end points of lines (values of sine and cosine) and has a diagonal that intercepts with the _tan_ of a circle. Both lines stop at the intercept. I don't know if the intercept is calculated or if both lines are clipped at the other one's respective value. Might you know which tutorial I mean? Check that out ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an almost trivial possibility: extend the tangent by some decent amount and clip it.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    tangent/.style={ % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25940/18228
        decoration={
            markings,% switch on markings
            mark=
                at position #1
                with
                {
                    \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
                }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    use tangent/.style={
        shift=(tangent point-#1),
        x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
        y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
    },
    use tangent/.default=1
]
\draw[very thick,tangent=.4](.5,4)to[bend right=35](5.5,.5);
\begin{scope}[overlay]
\clip(0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\draw[use tangent,blue](-3,0)--(3,0); % Better way to draw this line?
\end{scope}
\draw[<->](0,5)node[left]{$y$}--(0,0)--(7,0)node[below]{$x$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, there will be more elaborate solutions which pretend to be more elegant. ;-)

You do not even need intersections to find the intersections with the axes.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{mark tangent intersections with axes/.code={
\path let \p1=(tangent point-#1), 
\p2=($(tangent unit vector-#1)-(tangent point-#1)$)
in
({\x1-\y1*\x2/\y2},0) coordinate (x-intersection-#1) 
(0,{\y1-\x1*\y2/\x2}) coordinate (y-intersection-#1);},
mark tangent intersections with axes/.default=1
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    tangent/.style={ % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25940/18228
        decoration={
            markings,% switch on markings
            mark=
                at position #1
                with
                {
                    \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
                }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    use tangent/.style={
        shift=(tangent point-#1),
        x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
        y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
    },
    use tangent/.default=1
]
\draw[very thick,tangent=.4](.5,4)to[bend right=35](5.5,.5);

\draw[mark tangent intersections with axes,blue] 
(x-intersection-1) -- (y-intersection-1);
\draw[<->](0,5)node[left]{$y$}--(0,0)--(7,0)node[below]{$x$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have more than one tangent, use `\draw[mark tangent intersections with axes=2,...` and so on, the respective intersection points will be called `(x-intersection-2)`, `(y-intersection-2)` etc. Notice that this code will fail if the tangent is horizontal or vertical, so would intersections. One could add if statements checking if `\y2` or `\x2` is zero in case you want to make it fool proof(er).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes, `clip` is one way to go. I preferred calculating the intercepts directly because I wanted to allow for the possibility of adding labels/nodes beside the intercepts. I guess `clip` can be used together with the `intersections` library to achieve the same effect. So maybe `clip` is the most efficient way to go.

Comment: @HerrK. You do not even need intersections for this. I wrote a quick code.

Comment: @marmot Excellent and....elegant. +1

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to use the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) package:

[image]

**Use `\clip`:**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tzhelplines(7,6)
\tzaxes(7,6){$x$}[b]{$y$}[l]
\tzto[thick,bend right=35]"IC"(.5,4)(5.5,.5)
\clip (0,0) rectangle (5,5);  % clip
\settztangentlayer{main}      % main layer
\tztangentat[blue]{IC}{2}[0:4.5]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Find and use coordinates on axes:**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tzhelplines(7,6)
\tzaxes*(7,6){$x$}[b]{$y$}[l]
\tzto[thick,bend right=35]"IC"(.5,4)(5.5,.5)
% find points on axes
\settztangentlayer{main}
\tztangentat[draw=none]"tan"{IC}{2}[0:4.1]
\tzvXpointat{tan}{0}(A)
\tzhXpointat{tan}{0}(B)
% draw line
\tzline[blue](A)(B)   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Excellent package!