# Plot that demonstrate Newton's method

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

I am preparing some slides for numerical method classes. I have difficulty identify the best package to draw plot like below
[image]

I know there is software like Geogebra, but I prefer to do within latex. Any suggestions for a quick and convenient package?

Comment: Related/Duplicate? [How to draw tangent line of an arbitrary point on a path in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz)

Comment: thank you. But I also want mathematics there. My actual picture indeed include more maths than I show...

Comment: Here is another related post: [Extending a tangent line until x and y axes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433317/extending-a-tangent-line-until-x-and-y-axes)

Comment: You should really use the site search: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btikz-pgf%5D+tangent

Comment: @HenriMenke as I earlier mentioned, I want to add maths in addition to those tangent. I see none of those examples show maths there ...

Comment: @cpp123 It would be good if you were a bit more specific in your question. What part are you struggling with? The drawing of the curve and the tangent is covered by most of the answers provided in the previous comments. For the math part, what do you mean? Displaying the `F`, `x^{(k + 1)}` and `x^{(k)}` shown in the figure in your question? Then look at the documentation of the [TikZ package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or introductions to TikZ, this is the purpose of nodes. If you go with [pgfplots](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots), it will be a mix between the axes ticks and the nodes.

Comment: To back up my previous comment, you might want to look at [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/linear-regression/) or other examples on [the same website](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/plotting/). This might give you ideas to begin with.

Comment: thanks@KersouMan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,yscale=0.8]

% Axes
\draw[-latex,name path=xaxis] (-1,0) -- (12,0) node[above]{\large $x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-2) -- (0,8)node[right]{\large $y$};;

% Function plot
\draw[ultra thick, orange,name path=function]  plot[smooth,domain=1:9.5] (\x, {0.1*\x^2-1.5}) node[left]{$F(x)$};



% plot tangent line
\node[violet,right=0.2cm] at (8,4.9) {\large tangent};

\draw[gray,thin,dotted] (8,0) -- (8,4.9) node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt]{};
\draw[dashed, violet,name path=Tfunction]  plot[smooth,domain=4.25:9.5] (\x, {1.6*\x-7.9});



% x-axis labels
\draw (8,0.1) -- (8,-0.1) node[below] {$x^{(k)}$};
\draw [name intersections={of=Tfunction and xaxis}] ($(intersection-1)+(0,0.1)$) -- ++(0,-0.2) node[below,fill=white] {$x^{(k+1)}$} ;


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

yields:

[image]

I used the library *intersections* to get the coordinates of the intersection between the tangent and the x-axis lines. To this end, I saved both paths using
`name path=xaxis`
and
`name path=Tfunction`
for x-axis line and tangent line, respectively.

The function corresponds to 0.1*x^2-1.5.

Answer (score 9):

With `pgfplots` and `pgfplotstable`:

[image]

```
%\documentclass[]{article}
\documentclass[margin=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
% Input 1/2 =====
\newcommand\fxshow{e^{0.9x}-x^2}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\mywidth{8.9cm}

\tikzset{trig format=rad, 
declare function={
% Input 2/2 =====
f(\x)=exp(0.9*\x) -\x*\x;  
xStart=2.6;
Steps=4;
% Calc ====
xNew(\x)=\x-f(\x)/df(\x);
dx=0.01;      
df(\x)=( f(\x+dx) -f(\x) )/dx;
},}

% Start row
\pgfmathsetmacro\xStart{xStart}
\pgfmathsetmacro\fxnStart{f(xStart)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dfxnStart{df(xStart)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xNewStart{xNew(xStart)}
\pgfplotstableread[header=false, col sep=comma,
]{
0, \xStart, \fxnStart, \dfxnStart,  \xNewStart
}\newtontable

% Further rows
\pgfmathsetmacro\Steps{Steps}
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \n in {1,...,\Steps} {%%
\ifnum\n=1 \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]4}\of\newtontable \else
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]4}\of\nextrow \fi
\pgfmathsetmacro\xOld{\pgfplotsretval}
%
\pgfmathsetmacro\fxn{f(\xOld)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dfxn{df(\xOld)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xNew{xNew(\xOld)}
%
\edef\createnextrow{
\noexpand\pgfplotstableread[
col sep=comma,      row sep=crcr, 
]{
\n,   \xOld,   \fxn, \dfxn, \xNew \noexpand\\
}\noexpand\nextrow
}\createnextrow
%
% Concatenate in loop
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\temprow}{\nextrow}
%\n \pgfplotstabletypeset{\temprow} \\ % Show for test
}%%
% Concatenate with startrow
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\newtontable}{\temprow}

% Output =============================
\pgfmathsetmacro\dx{dx}

\newsavebox{\ExampleText}
\savebox\ExampleText{% ======================
\begin{minipage}{\mywidth}
% Title =======
$f(x) = \fxshow   \\[1em]
f'(x)\approx \dfrac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x},~~\Delta x=\dx \\[0.5em]
t_n(x) = f'(x_n)\cdot (x-x_n)+f(x_n) \\[0.5em]
x_0=\xStart,~~    x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}    $  \\[0.5em]
%Table =======
\pgfplotstabletypeset[column type=r, 
% Show integers as intgers and general number format:
every column/.style={postproc cell content/.style={
@cell content=\pgfmathifisint{##1}
        {\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{##1}}  
        {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,  fixed zerofill,  precision=5]{##1}}  
}}, 
%font=\footnotesize, 
display columns/0/.style={column name=$n$},
display columns/1/.style={column name=$x_n$},
display columns/2/.style={column name=$f(x_n)$},
display columns/3/.style={column name=$f'(x_n)$},
display columns/4/.style={column name=$x_{n+1}$},
every head row/.style={after row=\hline, before row=\hline},
every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
]{\newtontable} \\[0.5em]
%
\xdef\xRes{\xNew}
\pgfmathparse{f(\xRes)}
\xdef\yRes{\pgfmathresult}
{$\Rightarrow~ \boldsymbol{ x  \approx\xNew}$  }
\end{minipage}}%========================
%\usebox{\ExampleText} % Show for test

\begin{tikzpicture}[
font=\footnotesize, 
]
% Curve =============================
\begin{axis}[local bounding box=Curve,
%width=\mywidth, 
title={\usebox{\ExampleText}},
title style={align=left, anchor=south west, 
draw=none, text width=\mywidth, 
at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},   name=Example, 
},
trig format=rad, 
axis lines = center,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
axis line style = {-latex},
xlabel style={anchor=north},
ylabel style={anchor=east},
xmin=-3,      xmax=3,
%ymin=-0.5,     ymax=3.7,
%xtick={-1,-0.6,...,1},
%minor ytick={-0.5,0,...,3.5},
%legend pos=outer north east,
legend style={at={(0.0,-0.05)},anchor=north west},
legend cell align=left,
enlarge y limits=upper,
enlarge x limits,
clip=false, 
]
% Curve
\addplot[thick, domain=-1.5:3, blue]{f(x)}; 
\addlegendentry{$f(x)=\fxshow$}
% Tangents
\foreach \row in {0,...,\Steps}{%%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{0}\of\newtontable
\xdef\Index{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{1}\of\newtontable
\xdef\xS{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xSshow{\xS<0 ? \xS : "+\xS"}
%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{2}\of\newtontable
\xdef\yS{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ySshow{\yS<0 ? \yS : "+\yS"}
%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{3}\of\newtontable
\xdef\dyS{\pgfplotsretval}
% 
\pgfmathsetmacro\vR{0.4+1/\dyS}
\pgfmathsetmacro\vL{1.1+1/\dyS}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Pos{\row==3 || \row==999 ? -0.05 : 1.05}

\edef\nextplot{
\noexpand\addplot[red, domain=\xS-\vL:\xS+\vR, forget plot]{\dyS*(x-\xS)+\yS} node[pos=\Pos]{$t_\Index$}; 
\noexpand\addplot[red, mark=*, mark size=1.5pt, mark options={fill=white, draw=black}] coordinates{(\xS,\yS) };
\noexpand\addlegendentry[]{$t_\Index(x)=\dyS\cdot (x \xSshow) \ySshow$}
\noexpand\addplot[densely dashed, forget plot] coordinates{(\xS,\yS) (\xS,0)} node[below]{$x_\Index$};
}\nextplot
}%

% Zero of Curve
\addplot[mark=*, mark size=1.75pt, forget plot] coordinates{(\xRes,\yRes)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If this answer was your master thesis, it wouldn't be more scientific and prolific :)