# Tikz and Secant Line diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Hi I am looking for feedback to improve an existing program PLUS advice for a desired diagram in the same direction.

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.75,cap=round]
\tikzset{axes/.style={}}
%\draw[style=help lines,step=1cm, dotted] (-5.25,-5.25) grid (5.25,5.25);
% The graphic
\begin{scope}[style=axes]
\draw[->] (-.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5)-- (0,3) node[left] {$y$};
\foreach \x/\xtext in {1.5/x_{1}, 3/x_{2}}
 \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) 
node[below,fill=white,font=\normalsize]
  {$\xtext$};    
\foreach \y/\ytext in {1/y_{1}=f(x_{1}), 2.125/y_{1}=f(x_{2})}
  \draw[yshift=\y cm] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) 
  node[left,fill=white,font=\normalsize]
  {$\ytext$};
  %%%
 \draw[domain=.5:3.25,smooth,variable=\x,red,<->,thick] plot ({\x},{.5*(\x-1.5)*(\x-1.5)+1});
  %%%
\filldraw[black] (1.5,1) circle (1pt) node[above] {\scriptsize $P$};
\filldraw[black] (3,2.125) circle (1pt) node[left] {\scriptsize $Q$};
\draw[thick,blue!50,shorten >=-.5cm,shorten <=-.5cm] (1.5,1)--(3,2.125) 
node[midway,left] {\scriptsize Secant Line};
 %%%
 \draw[blue!50,thick,dashed] (1.5,1)--(3,1)--(3,2.125);
 \draw[blue!50] (3,1.1)--(2.9,1.1)--(2.9,1);
 \draw[decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},decorate,blue!50]
    (1.5,-.250) -- node[below=6pt] {$x_{2}-x_{1}$} (3,-.250);
 \draw[decoration={brace,mirror, raise=5pt},decorate,blue!50]
    (3,1) -- node[right=6pt] {$f(x_{2})-f(x_{1})$} (3,2.215);
 %%%
\filldraw[black] (1.5,1) circle (1pt) node[above] {\scriptsize $P$};
\filldraw[black] (3,2.125) circle (1pt) node[left] {\scriptsize $Q$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This will Output

[image]

I am trying to go here with the picture:

[image]

This is a bit beyond my programming skills I think ? PLease all suggestions welcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `decorations.markings` you can mark coordinates along the path, which then allow you to draw tangents. Note that drawing tangents has already been discussed at length [in this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25940/121799), and I am implicitly using the same approach. However, my code is an attempt to have a unified treatment of both of your requests, i.e. tangent and secants, so at first sight it looks quite different.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,calc,arrows.meta,bending}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,cap=round,mark pos/.style args={#1/#2}{%
postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,%
mark=at position #1 with {
\coordinate (#2);}}}}]
\tikzset{axes/.style={}}
%\draw[style=help lines,step=1cm, dotted] (-5.25,-5.25) grid (5.25,5.25);
% The graphic
\begin{scope}[style=axes]
  %%%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\posP}{0.38}
 \draw[red,{Latex[bend]}-{Latex[bend]},thick,mark
 pos/.list={\posP-0.005/p-0,\posP/P,\posP+0.005/p-2,0.5/q-4,0.62/q-3,0.74/q-2,0.86/q-1}] plot[domain=.5:3.25,samples=101,variable=\x] ({\x},{.5*(\x-1.5)*(\x-1.5)+1});
 \draw[red] let \p1=($(p-2)-(p-0)$),\n1={(\y1/\x1)*(1cm/1pt)}
 in ($(P)-1*(1,\n1)$) -- ($(P)+2*(1,\n1)$) node[right,anchor=north
 west,font=\scriptsize,text width=1cm]{slope $m$ $=$ instaneous rate \dots};
 \fill (P) circle (1pt) node[above,font=\scriptsize] {$P$};
 \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
 {\fill (q-\X) circle (1pt) node[below right,font=\scriptsize] {$Q_\X$};
 \path (P) -- (q-\X) coordinate[pos=-0.5] (L-\X) coordinate[pos={1.2+\X*0.3}] (R-\X);
 \draw[cyan,dashed] (L-\X) -- (R-\X) node[right,font=\scriptsize] (m\X) {slope $m_\X$}; }
 \draw[line width=2mm,-{Latex[bend]},red!20] ($(m1)+(0.5,0.1)$)
 to[out=-90,in=65] ++ (-0.2,-1.2);
  %%%
 %%%
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No Marmot, you can take them out. I am reviewing the out put . It is hard to read since the points are cluttered but feel free to change these. There is no hurry. I also would not know how to make the red arrow indicating the secants approach the tangent.

Comment: In short, make as many changes to the original as you require

Comment: @MathScholar Well, I could do that, but this would require me knowing what the target output is. Plus I do not know what " I also would not know how to make the red arrow indicating the secants approach the tangent" means. (Remember, I am just a simple marmot. ;-)

Comment: the target output is exactly the image(picture) above. I just provided a minimal example which I thought could lead there. Your welcome to change as much as you need I appreciate you contribution.

Comment: @MathScholar Is that closer now?

Comment: +1 a nice arrow!

Comment: @Marmot, excellent and beyond what I could program! Now I have some serious studying to do! Thanks Marmot.

Comment: @Marmot any advice on how to extend the red straight line more to the right containing the node[...] {Slope m= }? After that I can tweak and add a few more labels , I  think?

Comment: The (horizontal) position is determined by `($(P)+2*(1,\n1)$)` (where `\n1` is the slope). All you need to do is to replace `2` by something larger, e.g. `($(P)+2.5*(1,\n1)$)`. This means the line will then extend 2.5 units (instead of 2) to the right.

Comment: Got it! Perfect.

Comment: Trying to do it without extra libraries. The attempt is posted as answer. Any feedback would be appreciated  ;)

Answer (score 7):

I refactored the yesterday answer and added some new features.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}


\def\f(#1){((#1+3)/3+sin(#1+3))}
\def\fp(#1){Derive(1,\f(#1))}
\psset{unit=2}

\begin{document}
\multido{\r=2.0+-.1}{19}{%
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-1.6,-.6)(4.4,3.4)
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-1.6,-.6)(4.1,3.1)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt]{-1}{3.9}{\f(x)}
    %
    \psplotTangent[linecolor=blue]{1.6}{1}{\f(x)}
    \psplotTangent[linecolor=cyan,Derive={-1/\fp(x)}]{1.6}{.5}{\f(x)}
    %
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={135,90}]
        (*1.6 {\f(x)}){A}
        (*{1.6 \r\space add} {\f(x)}){B}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-120,-60},PointName={x_1,x_2},PointNameSep=8pt]
        (A|0,0){x1}
        (B|0,0){x2}
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={210,150},PointName={f(x_1),f(x_2)},PointNameSep=20pt]
        (0,0|A){fx1}
        (0,0|B){fx2}
    \pcline[nodesep=-.5,linecolor=green](A)(B)
    %
    \psset{linestyle=dashed}
    \psCoordinates(A)
    \psCoordinates(B)
    %
    \psset{linecolor=gray,linestyle=dashed,labelsep=4pt,arrows=|*-|*,offset=-16pt}
    \pcline(x1)(x2)
    \nbput{$x_2-x_1$}
    \pcline(fx2)(fx1)
    \nbput{$f(x_2)-f(x_1)$}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Secant, tangent, and normal lines are given free of charge!

Comment: Hey I like it but need the program in Tikz. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I can show the tangent but this space is too narrow to contain.

Comment: You can change the original program to allow for your space. Any response is appreciated

Comment: Nice animation (+1)

Comment: I really like this animation and will try this tomorrow with TiKz

Answer (score 2):

I see that @marmot has already given you the solution. This is just another way of doing it. Just an attempt to do it without using any extra libraries.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={func(\y) = 0.1*(\y-5)*(\y-5)+1;}]
\draw[domain=2:15,smooth,variable=\x,thick] plot ({\x},{func(\x)});
\draw[fill] (6.4,{func(6.4)})node[below]{p}circle (2pt)coordinate(p);
\foreach[count=\i] \x in {8.0,9.6,...,14.4}{
    \draw[fill] (\x,{0.1*(\x-5)*(\x-5)+1})node[below]{Q$_\i$} circle (2pt)coordinate(Q\i);
    \draw[thick,blue!80,dashed,shorten >=-2cm,shorten <=-2cm] (p) -- (Q\i)node[right=0.7cm](m\i){slope m$_\i$};
    }
\draw[thick,red!70,shorten >=-9cm,shorten <=-4cm] (p) -- (6.401,{func(6.401)});
\draw[-latex,line width=4mm,red!20] (m4.south east) to[out=-100, in=25] (m2.south east)node[below,anchor=north west,red]{slope $m=\ldots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks very good to me! (One reason why I did not go that way is that one may not necessarily plot a known function, but just draw some curve by other means, e.g. with `to[out=...,in=...]` or `.. (...) and (...) ..`. But as long as you do not go that way, this a very nice and compact way of achieving this.)

Comment: @nidhin Thank you for this. The program has its own merits as well. Thanks for sharing