# How to ensure that perpendicular lines appear perpendicular in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing a figure to illustrate the relationship between a curve, and its tangent and normal lines at a point. Due to the nature of the curve (cubic polynomial), I'm manually adjusting the x- and y-scales so that the plot appears "nice". This adjustment affects the appearance of the angle at which the tangent and normal intersect. How may I fix it so that these lines appear perpendicular. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,amsmath}
\begin{document}
    Find the equation of the tangent and normal lines shown below.
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,x=2.5cm,y=0.35cm,font=\footnotesize]
        \draw[thick,->,color=black] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[above right] {$x$};
        \draw[thick,->,color=black] (0,-15) -- (0,12) node[below right] {$y$};
        \foreach \y in {-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (-2pt,0pt);
        \draw[thick,smooth,samples=100,domain=-2.1:2.2,color=black] plot(\x,{3*(\x)^3-(\x)^2-10*(\x)+2}) node[above] {$y=3x^3-x^2-10x+2$};
        \draw[thick,smooth,samples=100,domain=0:3.0,color=blue] plot(\x,{-16+29*(\x)/4});
        \draw[thick,smooth,samples=100,domain=0:3.0,color=red] plot(\x,{-1141/232-4*(\x)/29});
        \draw[thick,dashed] (3/2,-41/8)--(3/2,0);
        \node[above] at (3/2,0) {$\tfrac{3}{2}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically the answer to your question is given in section **13.5.4 The Syntax of Distance Modifiers** of pgfmanual v3.1.4b. Call the point where the tangent touches the curve `p1` and another point on the tangent `p2`, then the normal is given by

```
\draw[red,thick]  ($ (p1)!3cm!90:(p2) $)  -- (p1);
```

where 90 is the angle and 3cm the distance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    Find the equation of the tangent and normal lines shown below.
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,x=2.5cm,y=0.35cm,font=\footnotesize]
        \draw[thick,->,color=black] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[above right] {$x$};
        \draw[thick,->,color=black] (0,-15) -- (0,12) node[below right] {$y$};
        \foreach \y in {-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (-2pt,0pt);
        \draw[thick,smooth,samples=100,domain=-2.1:2.2,color=black] plot(\x,{3*(\x)^3-(\x)^2-10*(\x)+2}) node[above] {$y=3x^3-x^2-10x+2$};
        \draw[thick,blue] (0,{-16+29*(0)/4}) -- (3,{-16+29*(3)/4})
         coordinate[pos=0] (p0) coordinate[pos=0.5] (p1) coordinate[pos=1] (p2);
        \draw[red,thick]  ($ (p1)!3cm!90:(p2) $)  -- (p1);
        \draw[thick,dashed] (3/2,-41/8)--(3/2,0);
        \node[above] at (3/2,0) {$\tfrac{3}{2}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you want to let Ti*k*Z do all the hard work for you. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25940) comes with a style that installs the tangent frame at a given point of the curve. (To avoid `dimensions too large` errors, we attach the tangent at a non-smooth plot that we do not draw.) The tangent is the x direction and the normal the y direction in a path in which the `use tangent` switches on the tangent frame. This is the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
    Find the equation of the tangent and normal lines shown below.
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,x=2.5cm,y=0.35cm,font=\footnotesize,
    tangent/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,% switch on markings
            mark=
                at position #1
                with
                {
                    \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
                    \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
                }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    use tangent/.style={
        shift=(tangent point-#1),
        x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
        y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
    },
    use tangent/.default=1]
        \draw[thick,->,color=black] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[above right] {$x$};
        \draw[thick,->,color=black] (0,-15) -- (0,12) node[below right] {$y$};
        \foreach \y in {-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (-2pt,0pt);
        \path[tangent=0.77,samples=101,domain=-2.1:2.2]plot(\x,{3*(\x)^3-(\x)^2-10*(\x)+2}) node[above] {$y=3x^3-x^2-10x+2$};
        \draw[thick,smooth,samples=101,domain=-2.1:2.2,color=black] plot(\x,{3*(\x)^3-(\x)^2-10*(\x)+2}) node[above] {$y=3x^3-x^2-10x+2$};
        \draw [blue, thick, use tangent] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
        \draw [red, thick, use tangent] (0,0) -- (0,5);
        \draw[thick,dashed] (3/2,-41/8)--(3/2,0);
        \node[above] at (3/2,0) {$\tfrac{3}{2}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks!