# Balloon shape with tangent in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]I want to draw the attached figure that I did in power point in Latex, I can't figure out an easy way to draw the tangent and I want to draw the balloon shape as 3d plot

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
   \draw[rotate=180] (-2,0.25)--++(8,0);
  \draw[rotate=180, fill=gray!30] (2,0.25) .. controls (9,6) and (-5,6) .. (2,0.25);
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm, yshift=-10cm]
  \def\rx{4}    % horizontal radius of the ellipse
  \def\ry{0.5}  % vertical radius of the ellipse
  \def\z{2}     % distance from center of ellipse to origin

  \pgfmathparse{asin(\ry/\z)}
  \let\angle\pgfmathresult

  \coordinate (h) at (0, \z);
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);      
  \coordinate (A) at ({-\rx*cos(\angle)}, {\z-\ry*sin(\angle)});
  \coordinate (B) at ({\rx*cos(\angle)}, {\z-\ry*sin(\angle)});
   \coordinate (C) at (3, 2);

  \draw[fill=gray!50] (A) -- (O) -- (B) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=gray!30] (h) ellipse ({\rx} and {\ry});
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Irregular shapes are always more difficult than regular shapes.  If d is tangent at the top, you need a cone which morphs into an off-center sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
   \draw[rotate=180] (-2,0)--++(8,0);
   \draw[ball color=gray!5, looseness=1.5] (0,0) to[out=-20,in=0] node[sloped, pos=0.3](P){} (0,-3) to[out=180, in=180+20] node[sloped, fill=black, inner xsep=40pt, inner ysep=0, yscale=0.4, pos=0.9](Q){} cycle;
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm, yshift=-10cm]
  \def\rx{2.5}    % horizontal radius of the ellipse
  \def\ry{0.3}  % vertical radius of the ellipse
  \def\z{1.5}     % distance from center of ellipse to origin

  \pgfmathparse{asin(\ry/\z)}
  \let\angle\pgfmathresult

  \coordinate (h) at (0, \z);
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);      
  \coordinate (A) at ({-\rx*cos(\angle)}, {\z-\ry*sin(\angle)});
  \coordinate (B) at ({\rx*cos(\angle)}, {\z-\ry*sin(\angle)});
  \coordinate (C) at (3, 2);
  \draw[left color=gray!50,right color=white] (A) -- (O) -- (B) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=gray!30] (h) ellipse ({\rx} and {\ry});
\end{scope}

\draw[<->, shorten >= -23pt] (O) -- (P);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Look at this question: [How to draw tangent line of an arbitrary point on a path in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz) as well.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I make the slopped line thin

Comment: @Diana for example via `yscale` to shrink it down. See the edited post.