# Draw a tangent to curve at specified angle using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tangent

I would like to draw a tangent line to a curve, and I know there are elegant solutions to do so (eg. [How to draw tangent line of an arbitrary point on a path in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz)). However, these approaches usually draw the tangent at a point that is specified by its *relative position* on the curve. Instead, what I would like to do is give a specified *angle* and have tikz find the position itself.
(I know there could be multiple, but for my purposes I don't have that issue.)

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,6) -- (0,0) -- (9,0);
    \draw[blue] (0,5) to[out=-5,in=100] (8,0);
    \begin{scope}[shift={(5.4,3.6)}]
        \draw[red,rotate=-30] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
        \draw (0,0) circle (3pt);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Essentially, what I'm after is how to automate the search for the "shift" parameter, which I here just eyeballed with trial & error.

Comment: While PGF can calculate the angle for a relative poisition (*time*) of a curve it doesn't provide a function to calculate the inverse. You will need some mathematical formula ([first derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:B%C3%A9zier_2_big.gif)) for that, I believe. You could also try a bunch of points, say `0`, `.05`, …, `.95`, `.1` and choose the one that's closest to the desired angle. It gets even more interesting when you're not looking at only one Bézier curve but a path comprised out of multiple segments.

Comment: Basically, you need to do the inverse of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/478001/1103067), i.e. finding a *t* for a specific angle.

Comment: Because I need two parallel lines in my case, it's easier to eyeball the shift parameter rather than using tangents and estimating the pos parameter. I can keep doing it this way, I was just wondering if there is a more elegant approach. Thanks though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `bezier bounding box` from the TikZ library `bbox` can do these types of calculations, but it is not meant for this purpose, so it takes some tricks to extract the coordinate.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox, intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\mya}{-30}
\draw (0,6) -- (0,0) -- (9,0);
\draw[blue] (0,5) to[out=-5, in=100] (8,0);
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=lbb, bezier bounding box]
\path[name path=curve, rotate=-\mya] (0,5) to[out=-5, in=100] (8,0);
\path[name path=max] ([yshift=-0.001pt]lbb.north west) -- ([yshift=-0.001pt]lbb.north east);
\path[name intersections={of=max and curve}] (intersection-1) coordinate(c);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=\mya}]
\draw[red] (c) +(-2,0) -- +(2,0);
\draw (c) circle[radius=3pt];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A curve with a tangent point and line]

Comment: Thanks!! This looks really promising – it's by far the least custom code of the solutions given so far. Would you please be able to explain what the two last lines in the scope do, so that I'm better able to adapt the code if needed?

Comment: The code rotates the curve by the given angle, finds the bounding box, and finds the intersection of the curve and this box -that is the maxima of the rotated curve. The maxima point is rotated back on the original curve and circle and line is drawn. You can change `\path`s to `\draw`s to see what is happening.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I propose a solution that uses a decoration and a `pic` element, the tangent line.

1. The decoration `phSTrajectory` takes one argument (the number of points) and creates equally spaced points `P_i` along the curve and the tips `U_i` of the tangent unit vectors.
2. The pic element `tangent` takes two arguments, the angle of the tangent we are looking for (**it must exist**) and the number of points, and draws the tangent line (an approximation).

In the figure, ther is your drawing of the tangent at -30 degrees in red, and the corresponding pic in black.  I added the tangent with sloppe -65 in thick red.

**Remark** I marked the corresponding point (a filled circle) for visual verification.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  phSTrajectory/.style={% nb of steps
    decoration={%
      markings,
      mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 1/#1 with {
        \tikzmath{%
          {
            \path (0, 0) coordinate[name=P_\pgfkeysvalueof{%
              /pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}];
            \path (1, 0) coordinate[name=tipU_\pgfkeysvalueof{%
              /pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}];
          };
        }
      }
    },
    postaction=decorate
  },
  pics/tangent/.style 2 args={% angle / numbrer of points
    code={
      \tikzmath{%
        integer \j;
        real \a;
        \j = -1;
        coordinate \M;
        for \i in {1, ..., #2}{%
          \M = ($(tipU_\i) -(P_\i)$);
          \a = {atan2(\My, \Mx)};
          if \a<-#1 then {%
            if \j==-1 then {%
              \j = \i -1;
              {
                \draw ($(P_\j)!-1!(tipU_\j)$) -- ($(P_\j)!1!(tipU_\j)$);
                \filldraw[blue] (P_\j) circle (1pt);
              };
            } else {};
          } else {};
        };
      }
    }
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[evaluate={\N = int(220);}]
  \draw (0, 6) -- (0, 0) -- (9, 0);
  \draw[blue, phSTrajectory={\N}] (0, 5) to[out=-5, in=100] (8, 0);
  \path pic {tangent={30}{\N}};
  \path pic[red, very thick] {tangent={65}{\N}};

  \begin{scope}[shift={(5.4, 3.6)}]
    \draw[red, rotate=-30] (-2, 0) -- (2, 0);
    \draw (0, 0) circle (3pt);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Am I understanding right that this basically computes the angle at many points to find the one closest to what I'm looking for?

Comment: Indeed.  It is close to the realm of numerical analysis.  In case you need a better precision, some work must be done.  I noticed that one can not keep increasing the number of points of the initial division.

Answer (score 4):

You can force the curve to pass through the tangency point `T` with a known angle. Like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (T) at (5.4,3.6);
  \draw (0,6) -- (0,0) -- (9,0);
  \draw[blue] (0,5) to[out=-5,in=150] (T) to [out=-30,in=100] (8,0);
  \draw[red] (T) ++ (150:3) --++ (-30:6);
  \draw (T) circle (3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've used this trick before.. alas, in this case it isn't really workable in my code because I've already used up the degrees of freedom for the curve itself.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by my comment, here's a mathematical solution that works like [`\pgfpointcurveattime`](https://tikz.dev/base-points#%5Cpgfpointcurveattime) and [`\pgftransformcurveattime`](https://tikz.dev/base-transformations#%5Cpgftransformcurveattime) but with `…atangle`.

For TikZ, I'm using `pos angle = <angle>` that switches out the curve timer for the curve angle timer.

The core of this answer is `\pgfpointcurveatangle@` which will “return” the time *t* as `\@time` which then will be forwarded by the `…curveatangle`s to the `…curveattime`s. (This technically does do work twice because the `…curveattime`s also return the angle for the use with `sloped`.)

Instead of PGFMath, I'm using `\fpeval` since I've run into problems with basic PGFmath.
This probably can be converted so that it uses the `fpu` library but I don't have much experience with it.

---

Using `pos angle` with any other path than an explicit Bézier should do nothing. “Explicit” means that it will only work with `.. controls` or the various `out`/`in` options.
While `arc`s are drawn as Bézier curves on the lowest level, they use a different timer and won't handle the angle timer.

Lastly, I've added a node to show what PGF thinks the angle of the tangent is which, expectedly, is a bit off.

---

To use it, just place a coordinate, node or pic along a curve and instead of `pos` (or its implicit versions like `midway`) use `pos angle`. If you want the node or pic also angled use `sloped` and possibly `allow upside down`.

In your case, I've added a pic called `cs` which just places three coordinates named `<name>`, `<name>-x` and `<name>-y` (where `<name>` is the name of the pic). The `pic cs` style can then be used to shift and rotate the coordinate system as if you were drawing in the pic.

Then you can draw your tangent as such:

```
\draw[blue] (0,5) to[out=-5,in=100]
  pic[pos angle=-30, sloped] (a) {cs} (8,0);
\draw[pic cs=a, red] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
\draw (a) circle[radius=3pt];
```

Don't forget `allow upside down` otherwise your cs might be rotated.
With

```
pics/cs/.prefix style={/tikz/allow upside down, /tikz/sloped}
```

you can make every `cs` pic automatically sloped and upside down.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\makeatletter
%% Utils
\def\pgfextractxy#1{\pgf@process{#1}\pgfgetlastxy}
\newcommand*\fpUnlessIf[1]{
  \edef\pgfmathresult{\fpeval{#1}}%
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1 \expandafter\@gobble
                    \else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi}
\newcommand*\fpsetmacro[2]{\edef#1{\fpeval{#2}}\typeout{#1 = #2}}
%% PGF
\def\pgfpointcurveatangle@#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \def\@time{1}\fpsetmacro\@tan{tand(#1)}%
  \pgfextractxy{#2}\@Ax\@Ay \pgfextractxy{#3}\@Bx\@By
  \pgfextractxy{#4}\@Cx\@Cy \pgfextractxy{#5}\@Dx\@Dy
  \fpsetmacro\@divisor{
    -3*\@Bx*\@tan+3*\@Cx*\@tan-\@Dx*\@tan-\@Ax*\@tan -\@Ay+3*\@By-3*\@Cy+\@Dy}%
  \fpUnlessIf{\@divisor==0}{% divide by 0?
    \fpsetmacro\@divnosqrt{%% calculate dividend (no sqrt part)
      -2*\@Bx*\@tan+\@Cx*\@tan+\@Ax*\@tan-\@Ay+2*\@By-\@Cy}%
    \fpsetmacro\@divsqrt{%% calculate divident (sqrt part)
      (-4*\@Bx*\@tan+2*\@Cx*\@tan+2*\@Ax*\@tan -2*\@Ay+4*\@By-2*\@Cy)^2
      -4*(\@Bx*\@tan-\@Ax*\@tan+\@Ay-\@By)
      *(3*\@Bx*\@tan-3*\@Cx*\@tan+\@Dx*\@tan-\@Ax*\@tan+\@Ay-3*\@By+3*\@Cy-\@Dy)}%
    \fpUnlessIf{\@divsqrt<0}{% sqrt(neg)?
      \fpsetmacro\@time{(.5*sqrt(\@divsqrt)+\@divnosqrt)/\@divisor}%
      \fpUnlessIf{\@time>=0&&\@time<=1}{%
        \fpsetmacro\@time{(-.5*sqrt(\@divsqrt)+\@divnosqrt)/\@divisor}}%
    }}}
\def\pgfpointcurveatangle#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \pgfpointcurveatangle@{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
  \pgfpointcurveattime{\@time}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
\def\pgftransformcurveatangle#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \pgfpointcurveatangle@{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
  \pgftransformcurveattime{\@time}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
% TikZ
\newif\iftikz@angletimer
\def\tikz@timer@curve{%
  \iftikz@angletimer
    \pgftransformcurveatangle{\tikz@time@angle}{\tikz@timer@start}
     {\tikz@timer@cont@one}{\tikz@timer@cont@two}{\tikz@timer@end}%
  \else
    \pgftransformcurveattime{\tikz@time}{\tikz@timer@start}
      {\tikz@timer@cont@one}{\tikz@timer@cont@two}{\tikz@timer@end}%
  \fi}%
\tikzset{
  pos angle/.code=%
    \edef\tikz@time@angle{#1}%
    \ifx\tikz@time@angle\pgfutil@empty\else
      \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@time@angle{\tikz@time@angle}\fi
    \tikz@angletimertrue,
  pos/.append code=\tikz@angletimerfalse}
\makeatother
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  cs/.pic={
   \coordinate (-x) at (1,0) coordinate (-y) at (0,1) coordinate () at (0,0);},
  pic cs/.style={shift={(#1)}, x={($(#1-x)-(#1)$)}, y={($(#1-y)-(#1)$)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,6) -- (0,0) -- (9,0);
    \draw[blue] (0,5) to[out=-5,in=100]
      pic[pos angle=-30, sloped] (a) {cs} (8,0);
    \draw[pic cs=a, red] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw (a) circle[radius=3pt];
    \node[below left] at (a) {
          \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{a}{center}}
                                    {\pgfpointanchor{a-x}{center}}
          \pgfmathresult};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I realize now that there's `\fp_compare…` which might be better than my “dirty” `\fpUnlessIf` but too late …

Comment: Woah! Impressive!! I feel a bit bad because with a similar amount of algebra, I could have just figured out the correct parametrization of the curve in my figure. But much appreciated!